# Arithmetic Sequences

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, arithmetic

An arithmetic sequence is a sequence of numbers of the form `a`,`a+n`,`a+2n`,`a+3n`, etc. In this case, `a` and `n` will both be either integers or decimals.

Given two inputs, `a`, `n`, and a top number value, return a list of numbers where the last term is **less than or equal to** the top number value.

The input can be formatted in any way, as well as the output.

***The catch to this problem is dealing with floating point arithmetic errors.***
For example, `0.1 + 0.3 * 3` is 1, however this will display `0.99999999999...` if you simply go `0.1 + 0.3 * 3`. We want `1`, not `0.99999999999...`

## Test Cases

`a=2, n=3, top=10: [2, 5, 8]`
`a=3, n=1.5, top=12: [3, 4.5, 6, 7.5, 9, 10.5, 12]`
`a=3.14159, n=2.71828, top=10: [3.14159, 5.85987, 8.57815]`
`a=0.1, n=0.3, top=2: [0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 1, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9]`

Shortest code wins. Good luck!

Comment: Is this supposed to be a standalone program, or a function? If a standalone program is provided, are there any requirements to the format of the input or output?

Comment: Function/standalone is fine. There is no specified input or output: the programmer will state both.

Comment: What do you mean by "floating points" in the first paragraph? If they're actual IEEE754 floating point numbers then most of your test cases don't make sense; so are they strings representing decimal floating point numbers? If so, to what precision?

Comment: I changed "floating points" to "decimals".

Comment: The input/output part should be specified in the question, not just in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### APL (22)

```
{⍵≤T:⍵,∇⍵+N⋄⍬}⊃A N T←⎕
```

Reads input from stdin as three whitespace-separated numbers.

This is actually shorter than using the index generator.

Comment: This problem was actually a fail. Using the `print` command, or the equivalent of it, rounded off floating points, so the challenge was not a challenge at all.

Answer (score 6):

### Non-golfed haskell, 32

```
f a n t=takeWhile(<=t)[a,a+n..]
```

I'd love to change takeWhile to take, but integer division can't be done with /, it needs to be done with `div`. If I go with / then I need to do implicit conversion which makes it that much longer.

Comment: That only works without the floating-point problems if called as `f :: Rational -> Rational -> Rational -> Rational` rather than e.g. `Double -> Double -> Double -> Double`. But I doubt output in the form `[1 % 10,2 % 5,7 % 10,1 % 1,13 % 10,8 % 5,19 % 10]` will be accepted.

Comment: @leftaroundabout If it was my problem, I'd accept that output! (But it's not.)

Answer (score 5):

### J, <strike>34</strike> <strike>33</strike> 31 characters

```
({.+i.@>:@([:<.1{[%~{:-{.)*1{[)
```

I'm sure there's room for improvement here.

Usage:

```
   ({.+i.@>:@([:<.1{[%~{:-{.)*1{[)2 3 10
2 5 8
```

We can give the verb a name for an extra three characters:

```
   s=.({.+i.@>:@([:<.1{[%~{:-{.)*1{[)
   s 2 3 10
2 5 8
```

Previously:

```
((0-.~]*]<:2{[)(((i.100)*1{[)+{.))
```

Thought I'd have a go at doing this in Golfscript and got as far as `.3$- 2$/1+,{2$*}%{3$+}%` before realising Golfscript doesn't seem to do floats. Bugger.

Answer (score 4):

#### bash 12:

```
seq $1 $2 $3
```

Haha - who would have thought that? Silly'o'bash which normally just handles Integer arithmetic (9/10 = 0) can handle floating points that way:

```
./cg-6228-arithmetic-sequences.sh 2 3 10
2
5
8
./cg-6228-arithmetic-sequences.sh 3 1.5 12
3,0
4,5
6,0
7,5
9,0
10,5
12,0
```

Other test-cases omitted for brevity. I have to mention that you can change the locale, if you're irritated by 10,5 which is the continental way to say 10.5. ;)

Comment: How very interesting!

Comment: This could be 3 bytes as a function: `seq` (maybe)

Answer (score 3):

#### Ruby 34

```ruby
s=->a,n,t{p a;s[a+n,n,t]if a+n<=t}
```

*Input:* the three function parameters

*Output:* the sequence numbers are printed, one per line

Ideone link: http://ideone.com/SahPs

Answer (score 3):

### [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 26

```
s=:1 :']+u*[:i.@<.@>:u%~-'
```

There's some interesting syntax to use this definition.

```
   10(2 s)1
1 3 5 7 9
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby - 28

```
((t-a)/n).times{|i|p(a+i*n)}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 5 bytes

```
Range
```

Arguments are a,top,n in that order. I'm assuming that decimal points at the end are okay.

Answer (score 2):

#### Scala 52

```
val x,?,z=BigDecimal(readLine)
x to z by?map println
```

Give inputs `a`,`n` and `top` in the separate line.
Each entry of the output will be listed in the separate line.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica <s>39</s> 37

```
Table[#+#2 k,{k,0,Quotient[#3-#,#2]}]&
```

**Usage**

```
Table[#1 + #2 k, {k, 0, Quotient[#3 - #1, #2]}] &[2, 3, 10]
Table[#1 + #2 k, {k, 0, Quotient[#3 - #1, #2]}] &[3, 1.5, 12]
Table[#1 + #2 k, {k, 0, Quotient[#3 - #1, #2]}] &[3.14159, 2.71828, 10]
Table[#1 + #2 k, {k, 0, Quotient[#3 - #1, #2]}] &[0.1, 0.3, 2]
```

[image: sequence output]

Answer (score 2):

### Swift, 90

Not quite as short as the other ones here but this doesn't use a builtin to compute the sequence, nor does it operate on a standard float type.  It declares a function `f(a:n:t:)` that takes the numbers in and prints the sequence to stdout.

```
import Foundation
func f(a:Decimal,n:Decimal,t:Decimal){var x=a
while x<=t{print(x)
x+=n}}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/M7cgv6hEwS2/NC8lsSQzP48rrTQvWSFNI9HKJTU5MzcxRycPziqBsTSryxKLFCpsE7nKMzJzUhUqbGxLqguKMvNKNCo0uSq0bfNqa7lAZhjoGQL1G@gZA/Uaaf7/DwA) (with hardcoded test case)

I learned a few things while doing this that surprised me:

- [Swift's range builtin](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range) is only iterable for integers, unlike in Python where you can specify the step size.
- [Assignment operators in Swift return Void](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID62), so I couldn't abbreviate the body of the while loop to `print(x+=n)`. I tried it; it just printed `()` a bunch of times.
- `Decimal` values are not converted to `Double` when printing. If you replace `Decimal` in the declaration with `Double`, it prints `1.0` and `1.9000000000000001` rather than `1` and `1.9`. On the other hand, this proves that it is avoiding floating-point rounding errors, as the question specified.
- There is no version of the `<=` operator that lets you compare a `Decimal` to any other number type, so I can't make the function declaration shorter by changing `t`'s type.

  - In fact, even though [`Decimal` is `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal#relationships), it is not [`FloatingPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint).

You could shave off two bytes by allowing the input to be mutated (changing the function signature to `f(a:inout Decimal,n:Decimal,t:Decimal)`, as this eliminates the need for the variable `x`.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript 70

```
s=prompt().split(",");for(n=0;(p=s[0]-0+n*s[1]-0)<=s[2]-0;n++)alert(p)
```

input in the form `a,n,top`

Comment: The code gives floating-point arithmetic errors. I, however, used a different test case: I will add it to the list.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 37 chars

```
for(($_,$n,$t)=<>;$_<=$t;$_+=$n){say}
```

Input a, n, and top, each number on a separate line. The list is output with newlines separating the values. Run with `perl -M5.010` (or `perl -E`).

Answer (score 1):

## Python (245)

Input should be given with a space in between, e.x. `0.1 0.3 0.5`

```
a=raw_input().split()
I,F=int,float
D='.'
b=[[I(i.replace(D,'')),len(i.split(D)[1:])]for i in a[:2]]
a=map(F,a)
c=max(b,key=lambda x:x[1])[1]
for i in b:i[0]*=10**(c-i[1])
print [(b[0][0]+i*b[1][0])/10.0**c for i in range(I((a[2]-a[0])/a[1]+1))]
```

It avoids floating point errors by turning each floating point into a list containing two values: the number without the decimal point, and the number of significant digits.
`example: 1.34 -> [134, 2]`

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 37

```
a,n,t=input()
while a<=t:print a;a+=n
```

Grabs input in the form `a, n, top`, and prints out the numbers on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

#### C# <s>120</s> 74

```c#
void A(float a,float n,int t){Console.Write(a+" ");a+=n;if(a<=t)A(a,n,t);}
```

**Edit:** New version - recursive and a lot shorter than using LINQ :)

*Input:* the three parameters of method `A`

*Output:* the numbers in the sequence are printed to console, separated by spaces.

Test link: http://ideone.com/o7g6k

> *Previous version (using LINQ):*

```c#
IEnumerable<float>A(float a,float n,int t){return Enumerable.Range(0,int.MaxValue).Select(i=>a+n*i).TakeWhile(s=>s<=t);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 83

```
<?function a($x,$i,$t){while($r<$t){$r=$x+$i*$g++;$s.=($r<$t?$r." ":"");}echo$s;}?>
```

Wish I could remove "function" but there's no shorter declaration for that in PHP. Handy that PHP uses untyped variables!

Usage:
a(2,3,10);
Returns:
2 5 8

Comment: You can save two bytes by omitting the final `?>`.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 53

```
<?for(list(,$a,$n,$x)=$argv;$a<=$x;$a+=$n)echo"$a ";
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 3 bytes

```
seq
```

Built in function with arguments from (`a`), to `(top`) and by (`n`)

usage `seq(a,top,n)` eg

```
seq(2,10,3)
```

output numeric vector

```
2 5 8
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 20

```
Prompt A,N,T:For(I,A,T,N:Disp I:End
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
↑≤⁰¡+⁴²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr///ihpHiiaTigbDCoSvigbTCsv///zEuNf8z/zEy)