# Golf the xᵗʰ root of x

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic

While bored in high-school (when I was half my current age...), I found that \$f(x) = x^{x^{-1}}\$ had some interesting properties, including e.g. that the maximum \$f\$ for \$0 ≤ x\$ is \$f(e)\$, and that the [binding energy per nucleon](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Binding_energy_curve_-_common_isotopes.svg) of an isotope can be approximated as [\$6 × f(x ÷ 21)\$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B6%20(x%2F21)%5E(x%2F21)%5E(-1),%20%7Bx,%200,%20140%7D%5D)...

Anyway, write the shortest function or program that calculates the x<sup>th</sup> root of x for any number in your language's domain.

### Examples cases

#### [For all languages](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex%5E-1+for+x+from+0+to+5)

```
     -1   >       -1
   ¯0.2   >    -3125
   ¯0.5   >        4
    0.5   >     0.25
      1   >        1
      2   >    1.414
      e   >    1.444 
      3   >    1.442
    100   >    1.047
  10000   >    1.001
```

#### [For languages that handle complex numbers](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex%5E-1+for+x+from+-5+to+5)

```
   -2   >        -0.7071i
    i   >            4.81         
   2i   >    2.063-0.745i
 1+2i   >   1.820-0.1834i
 2+2i   >   1.575-0.1003i
```

#### For languages that handle infinities

```
-1/∞   >   0    (or ∞ or ̃∞)
   0   >   0    (or 1 or ∞)
 1/∞   >   0
   ∞   >   1
  -∞   >   1
```

#### For languages that handle both infinities and complex numbers

```
 -∞-2i   >   1      (or ̃∞)
```

---

<sup>`̃∞` denotes [directed infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_infinity).</sup>

Comment: Here is a [Wolfram Alpha plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex%5E-1+for+x+from+0+to+5) for positive real `x`. If you omit the `x` limits in the query, Wolfram Alpha will include negative values of `x` where the function value depends on a choice of "branch" for the complex logarithm (or for a similar complex function).

Comment: What about for languages that do not handle power of decimals?

Comment: @KennyLau Feel free to post with a note that says so, especially if the algorithm would work, had the language supported it.

Answer (score 39):

## TI-BASIC, 3 bytes

```
Ans×√Ans
```

TI-BASIC uses tokens, so `Ans` and `×√` are both one byte.

#### Explanation

`Ans` is the easiest way to give input; it is the result of the last expression. `×√` is a function for the x'th root of x, so for example `5×√32` is 2.

Comment: As far as I am aware `ans` would count as hardcoding inputs into variables and does not seem to be an accepted input method for [tag:code-golf]. In that case, please make a full program or a function.

Comment: @flawr I can see what you're saying but it seems it's always been done like this. Maybe it warrants a meta post?

Comment: `Ans` is STDIN/STDOUT for TI-Basic.

Comment: `stdin` and `stdout` are text streams, usually for interactive text input and output. `Ans` is not interactive, unlike some other functions in TI-BASIC, which are interactive.

Comment: @Timtech Certainly not. There are functions like `Input` and `Prompt`.

Comment: You can vote on the validity of `Ans` [on meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8580/29750).

Comment: What I meant is that `Ans` is the only way for functions to take input and return output without messing with the global variables (technically `Ans` is global, but I'm referring to the `A`, `B`, etc.)

Comment: Question: Are there more than 256 tokens? If so, your byte count is invalid.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Yes, but they are two bytes. There are 256 (actually a little less) one-byte tokens.

Comment: @flawr The reason `Ans` is usually accepted is because its value is set by any expression (expressions are separated by `:`). Therefore something like `1337:prgmXTHROOT` would input 1337, which looks a lot like input via CLAs in a normal language.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/tokens

Answer (score 24):

## Jelly, 2 bytes

```
*İ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=KsSw&input=&args=Mg)

#### How it works

```
*İ    Main link. Input: n

 İ    Inverse; yield 1÷n.
*     Power (fork); compute n ** (1÷n).
```

Comment: Jelly doesn't have a stack. A dyad follow by a monad in a monadic chain behaves like APL's forks.

Comment: No, J's `^%` is a hook (which do not exist in Dyalog APL), not a fork. Jelly and APL code is difficult to compare since Jelly is left-to-right. The nearest equivalent would be `÷*⊢` (also a fork), which computes `(1/x)**x` because of the different direction. Since Jelly's atoms aren't overloaded (they are either monadic or dyadic, but never both), there can be monadic 1,2,1- and 2,1-forks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Naturally, I'm quite intrigued by Jelly (which I still think should be named ȷ or something similar.)

Answer (score 16):

## Javascript (ES2016), 11 bytes

```
x=>x**(1/x)
```

I rarely ever use ES7 over ES6.

Comment: `x=>x**x**-1` also works, again for 11 bytes.

Comment: All hail the new exponentiation operator!

Answer (score 15):

### Python 3, 17 bytes

```py
lambda x:x**(1/x)
```

Self-explanatory

Comment: I quite like `lambda x:x**x**-1`, but it's not shorter.

Comment: @Seeq Your expression is the same length, but it has the advantage of working in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Python 2's shortest is `lambda x:x**x**-1`, so it is the same in 2 and 3.

Comment: I couldn't find this answer for ages and was really annoyed when I did.

Answer (score 11):

## J, 2 bytes

```
^%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGulEKf6PzU5I18hTUEj3lAh3kDPCESYKoCwoYKRgpGeuaGFkYWCsYKhgQEIGxhocsF1GCkYZBkCsZGCIRAbZRlp/gcA).

#### How it works

```
^%  Monadic verb. Argument: y

 %  Inverse; yield 1÷y.
^   Power (hook); compute y ** (1÷y).
```

Comment: I was gonna write this answer. I'm too slow at this.

Comment: @Bijan Over a year too slow, it seems. :P

Comment: I see, I've only been golfing for a week now.

Answer (score 11):

## Haskell, <s>12</s> 11 bytes

Thanks @LambdaFairy for doing some magic:

```
(**)<*>(1/)
```

My old version:

```
\x->x**(1/x)
```

Comment: `(**)<*>(1/)` is 11 bytes.

Comment: @LambdaFairy Thanks! Do you mind explaining? It looks like you are doing some magic with partially applied functions but as I am quite new to Haskell I do not really understand how this works=)

Comment: This uses the fact that a 1-argument function can be considered an applicative functor (the "reader monad"). The `<*>` operator takes an applicative that produces a function, and an applicative that produces a value, and applies the function to the value. So in this case, a mind-bending way to apply a 2-argument function to a 1-argument function.

Comment: The function `<*>` takes 3 arguments, two functions `f` and `g` and an argument `x`. It is defined as `(<*>) f g x = f x (g x)`, i.e. it applies `f` to `x` and `g x`. Here it's partially applied to `f` and `g` leaving out `x`, where `f = (**)` and `g = (1/)` (another partially applied function (a section) that calculates the reciprocal value of it's argument). So `( (**)<*>(1/) ) x` is `(**) x ((1/) x)` or written in infix: `x ** ((1/) x)` and with the section resolved: `x ** (1/x)`. -- Note: `<*>` is used in function context here and behaves differently in other contexts.

Comment: @nimi So it's the equivalent of the `S` combinator i.e. S(**)(1/)?

Comment: @Neil: [yes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23095335).

Answer (score 9):

### Pyth, 3 bytes

```
@QQ
```

Trivial challenge, trivial solution...

#### (noncompeting, 1 byte)

```
@
```

This uses the implicit input feature present in a version of Pyth that postdates this challenge.

Comment: Does this solution predate the feature of implicit input?

Comment: @KennyLau Yes, by a long time. But I've edited the one-byte solution in anyway.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript ES6, 18 bytes

```
n=>Math.pow(n,1/n)
```

Answer (score 8):

### Java 8, 18 bytes

```
n->Math.pow(n,1/n)
```

Java isn't in last place?!?!

Test with the following:

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Main {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Test test = n->Math.pow(n,1/n);
    System.out.println(test.xthRoot(6.0));
  }
}

interface Test {
  double xthRoot(double x);
}
```

Comment: It's the fact that it's a function

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, <s>8</s> <s>7</s> <s>4</s> 7 bytes

```
#^#^-1&
```

<s>More [builtin-only](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6228/arithmetic-sequences/74826#74826) answers, and now even shorter!</s> Nope.
<s>By definition, the next answer should be 13 bytes. (Fibonacci!)</s> The pattern is still broken. :(

Comment: #^#^-1& saves 1 byte.

Comment: NOW it is golfed.

Comment: NOW it is golfed.

Comment: When Mthmtca is released, we are going to rule this board.

Comment: Hmm...time to look through my answers and make a compressed version of every builtin...

Comment: Surely just `Surd` isn't valid as it requires two arguments?

Comment: Oh...reverting.

Answer (score 6):

## R, <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
function(x)x^x^-1
```

-2 bytes thanks to @Flounderer

Comment: Why not `x^(1/x)` ? Edit: `x^x^-1` seems to work too.

Comment: That's a snippet, and apparently people don't like snippets.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy it is the definition of a function.

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 5 bytes

```
t-1^^
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dC0xXl4&input=Mmo)

```
t       % implicit input x, duplicate
 -1     % push -1
   ^    % power (raise x to -1): gives 1/x
    ^   % power (raise x to 1/x). Implicit display
```

Answer (score 6):

## Java, 41 bytes

```
float f(float n){return Math.pow(n,1/n);}
```

Not exactly competitive because Java, but why not?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I think you might be missing a return type on this function.

Comment: Oops, got sloppy.  A Java 8 answer already beat this one of course...

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, 6 bytes

```
rd_W##
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cmRfVyMj&input=Mg)

#### How it works

```
rd     e# Read a double D from STDIN and push it on the stack.
  _    e# Push a copy of D.
   W   e# Push -1.
    #  e# Compute D ** -1.
     # e# Compute D ** (D ** -1).
```

Answer (score 5):

## Perl 5, 10 bytes

9 bytes plus 1 for `-p`

```
$_**=1/$_
```

Answer (score 5):

## NARS APL, 2 bytes

```
√⍨
```

NARS supports the `√` function, which gives the ⍺-th root of ⍵. Applying commute (⍨) gives a function that, when used monadically, applies its argument to both sides of the given function. Therefore `√⍨ x` ↔ `x √ x`.

#### Other APLs, 3 bytes

```
⊢*÷
```

This is a function train, i.e. `(F G H) x` ↔ `(F x) G H x`.  Monadic `⊢` is identity, dyadic `*` is power, and monadic `÷` is inverse. Therefore, `⊢*÷` is *x* raised to 1/*x*.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 15 Bytes

```
a=->n{n**n**-1}
```

Ungolfed:

`->` is the *stabby* lambda operator where `a=->n` is equivalent to `a = lambda {|n|}`

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2 - 56 bytes

The first actual answer, if I'm correct. Uses Newton's method.

```
n=x=input();exec"x-=(x**n-n)/(1.*n*x**-~n);"*999;print x
```

Comment: Functions are okay.

Answer (score 5):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 125 bytes

```
15k?ddsk1-A 5^*sw1sn0[A 5^ln+_1^+ln1+dsnlw!<y]syr1<y1lk/*sz[si1[li*li1-dsi0<p]spli0<p]so0dsw[lzlw^lwlox/+lw1+dswA 2^!<b]dsbxp
```

Unlike the other dc answer, this works for *all* real \$x\$ greater than or equal to \$1 (\$1 ≤ x$). Accurate to 4-5 places after the decimal.

I would have included a TIO link here, but for some reason this throws a segmentation fault with the version there (`dc 1.3`) whereas it does *not* with my local version (`dc 1.3.95`).

#### Explanation

As **dc** does not support raising numbers to non-integer exponents to calculate \$x^\frac1x\$, this takes advantage of the fact that:

$$x^\frac1x = e^\frac{\ln x}x$$

So, to calculate \$\ln(x)\$, this also takes advantage of the fact that:

$$\int \frac1x dx = \ln(x) + c$$

whose definite integral from \$1\$ to \$b = x\$ is numerically-approximated in increments of \$10^{-5}\$ using the following summation formula:

$$\int_1^b \frac1x dx = \sum_{i=1}^{10^{5}(b-1)} \frac 1 {10^5 + i}$$

The resulting sum is then multiplied by \$\frac1x\$ to get \$\frac{\ln(x)}x\$. \$e^{\frac{\ln(x)}x}\$ is then finally calculated using the \$e^x\$ Maclaurin Series to 100 terms as follows:

$$e^x=\sum^{10^2}_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

This results in our relatively accurate output of \$x^\frac1x\$.

Comment: +1 This has got to be one of the best dc answers out there. I'm bookmarking this!

Comment: @KritixiLithos Thank you! I appreciate the kind words. :)

Comment: This is why we love this site (sorry Jelly people).

Answer (score 4):

### Seriously, 5 bytes

```
,;ì@^
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LDvDrEBe&input=NQ)

Explanation:

```
,;ì@^
,;     input, dupe
  ì@   1/x, swap
    ^  pow
```

Answer (score 4):

## , 5 chars / 7 bytes

```
Мű⁽ïï
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=100&code=%D0%9C%C5%B1%E2%81%BD%C3%AF%C3%AF)</kbd>

Trivial.

Answer (score 4):

### [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE/commit/9e0140f09cee5922e3931615c31216eb387738ce) (commit 29), 6 bytes

```
D1_R^^
```

Explanation:

```
D      - duplicate top
 1_    - load -1
   R   - rotate
    ^  - ^**^
     ^ - ^**^
```

Comment: Can haz link pls?

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant there's no implementation available. Yes, the interpreter doesn't have to be *hosted*, just a link to the repo / source (or docs) will suffice

Answer (score 4):

## [Pylons](https://github.com/morganthrapp/Pylons-lang), 5 bytes.

```
ideAe
```

How it works.

```
i # Get command line input.
d # Duplicate the top of the stack.
e # Raise the top of the stack to the power of the  second to the top element of the stack.
A # Push -1 to the stack (pre initialized variable).
e # Raise the top of the stack to the power of the second to the top element of the stack.
  # Implicitly print the stack.
```

Answer (score 4):

## Japt, 3 bytes

```
UqU
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VXFV&input=NA==)

Very simple: `U` is the input integer, and `q` is the root function on numbers.

Answer (score 4):

### C++, 48 bytes

```c++
#include<math.h>
[](auto x){return pow(x,1./x);}
```

The second line defines an anonymous lambda function. It can be used by assigning it to a function pointer and calling it, or just calling it directly.

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/fork/apfznO)

Comment: Does `^` not work in C++ as it does in C?

Comment: @minerguy31: `^` is bitwise xor in C (and C++).

Answer (score 4):

### C, 23 bytes

```
#define p(a)pow(a,1./a)
```

This defines a macro function `p` which evaluates to the `a`th root of `a`.

Thanks to Dennis for reminding me that `gcc` doesn't require `math.h` to be included.

Thanks to @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ for reminding me that the space after the first `)` is not needed.

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/fork/8FHRht)

Comment: With GCC, you don't need to include math.h.

Comment: -1 byte: `#define p(a)pow(a,1./a)`

Answer (score 4):

## [Milky Way 1.6.5](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way), 5 bytes

```
'1'/h
```

---

#### Explanation

```
'      ` Push input
 1     ` Push the integer literal
  '    ` Push input
   /   ` Divide the STOS by the TOS
    h  ` Push the STOS to the power of the TOS
```

> x**(1/x)

---

#### Usage

```
$ ./mw <path-to-code> -i <input-integer>
```

Answer (score 4):

### [O](https://github.com/phase/o), 6 bytes

```
j.1\/^
```

No online link because the online IDE doesn't work (specifically, exponentiation is broken)

Explanation:

```
j.1\/^
j.      push two copies of input
  1\/   push 1/input (always float division)
     ^  push pow(input, 1/input)
```

Comment: oh hey you did it yay

Answer (score 4):

## C# - <s>18</s> <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```
float a(float x){return Math.Pow(x,1/x);}
```

-2 byes thanks to @VoteToClose

[Try it out](https://repl.it/Bp8C/9)

Note:

> First actual attempt at golfing - I know I could do this better.

Comment: Welcome to the crowd! It is exactly because of newcomers that I make trivial challenges like this.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for informing me about this

Comment: @crayzeedude No problem at all. Nice job and again, welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Does C# have `float`?

Comment: Indeed it does.

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 9 bytes

```
x->x^x^-1
```

This is shorter than the alternatives `x->x^(1/x)` and `x->sqrtn(x,x)`. It uses the right-associativity of `^` and the strong binding of the unary `-`. GP isn't quite functional enough to curry `(a,b)->sqrtn(a,b)` into `(x)->sqrtn(x,x)`; the best it can manage is `x->call(sqrtn,[x,x])` which is far too long.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP 5.6, <s>32</s> <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
function($x){echo$x**(1/$x);}
```

or

```
function($x){echo$x**$x**-1;}
```

<sub>30->29, thank you Dennis!</sub>

Answer (score 3):

## Awk, 8 bytes

```
$1^$1^-1
```

A shell command to check it

```
awk '{print $1^$1^-1}'
```

---

Longer version (+1) with

```
$1^(1/$1)
```

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB, 11bytes

```
@(x)x^(1/x)
```

Creates an anonymous function. This will work with all test cases including complex numbers and infinities.

This also works with **Octave**. You can try online [here](http://octave-online.net). Simply enter something like:

```
f=@(x)x^(1/x)
```

At the command line of the online interpreter, then do:

```
f(-1)
```

To test.

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 25 bytes, type: `double`

Bare form of a lambda expression:

```cs
x=>System.Math.Pow(x,1/x)
```

The expression can be assigned to a function variable, e.g. (`Func<double, double>`), ...

`System.` can be omitted, if `using System;` is used (but more bytes).

Complete **test program (143 bytes)** with the input of the question:

```cs
using System;class P{static void Main(){Array.ForEach(new double[]{-.2,-.5,.5,1,2,Math.E,3,100,10000},x=>Console.WriteLine(Math.Pow(x,1/x)));}}
```

**Result:**

```
-3125
4
0,25
1
1,4142135623731
1,44466786100977
1,44224957030741
1,0471285480509
1,0009214583193
```

## C#, 37 bytes, type: `Complex`

```cs
x=>System.Numerics.Complex.Pow(x,1/x)
```

Also the assembly for `System.Numerics` needs to be referenced.
The division operator is overloaded for complex arguments.

**Test program (189 bytes)** with the input of the question for complex numbers:

```cs
using System;using C=System.Numerics.Complex;class P{static void Main(){Array.ForEach(new C[]{new C(-2,0),new C(0,1),new C(0,2),new C(1,2),new C(2,2)},x=>Console.WriteLine(C.Pow(x,1/x)));}}
```

**Result:**

```
(4,32963728535968E-17, -0,707106781186548)
(4,81047738096535, 0)
(2,0628722350809, -0,745007062179724)
(1,81984053615444, -0,183434723804562)
(1,57500291115344, -0,100274868564155)
```

**Test program (264 bytes)** with infinity:

```cs
using System;using C=System.Numerics.Complex;class P{static void Main(){var p=double.PositiveInfinity;var n=double.NegativeInfinity;Array.ForEach(new C[]{new C(-1/p,0),new C(0,0),new C(1/p,0),new C(p,0),new C(n,0),new C(n,2) },x=>Console.WriteLine(C.Pow(x,1/x)));}}
```

**Result:**

```
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(1, 0)
(1, 0)
(1, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vitsy](http://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), 4 + 1 (function declaration) = 5 bytes

Hey, look, my language actually does this. Go figure.

```
Di^^
D    Duplicate the top item (input)
 i   Push -1.
  ^  Pop top (-1), put the second to top to the power of the popped item (x^-1)
   ^ Same as above, except we now have the desired number.
```

This is a function that leaves the value requested on the stack. For view-ability, I have also made the program output on the Try it Online! link.

[Try it Online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=MW1OCkRpXl4&input=&args=LjU)

Comment: -1: Anonymous functions are allowed.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ Unfortunately, that's what I thought. However, I was informed that I would have to include the return character before the function in order for it to be valid.

Answer (score 3):

## [Bean](https://github.com/patrickroberts/bean), 11 bytes

Hexdump:

```
00000000 26 4c a0 43 95 4c a5 3a 8e 20 43  &L C.L¥:. C
0000000b
```

Equivalent JavaScript:

```
A**(1/A)
```

Implicitly converts first line of input to number as `A` and implicitly outputs the result of the expression.

#### [Try the demo here.](https://patrickroberts.github.io/bean/#h=JkygQ5VMpTqOIEM=&i=LTAuMg==&f=0&w=1)

#### [Try the test suite here.](https://patrickroberts.github.io/bean/#h=JlfQgNPQgKB3IICIQKBDTKBDlUylOo4gQyCAe1ZYgQAK&i=LTEKLTAuMgotMC41CjAuNQoxCjIKMwoxMDAKMTAwMDA=&f=0&w=1)

Answer (score 2):

## Codename Dragon, 16 bytes

```
a=<>;dispa^(1/a)
```

I'm abusing the lack of a syntax error.

Ungolfed:

```
disp((a=<>)^(1/a))
```

This is a simple program that takes input through `<>`.

You can find an interpreter [here](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Codename-Dragon/blob/master/CDragon.js), no github site yet.

Answer (score 2):

## Jolf, 5 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=XmovMWo)

```
^j/1j
 j    input
^ /1j to the 1/j pow.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Gnuplot, 13 bytes

```
f(x)=x**(1/x)
```

or

```
f(x)=x**x**-1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Racket, <strike>28</strike> 22 bytes

```
(λ(n)(expt n(/ 1 n)))
```

@cat gets credit for the 6 byte save. Thanks!

Seriously, Racket is impossible to golf with :). Nothing to see here, move along!

Comment: You can do `(λ(n)(expt n(/ 1 n)))` as an anonymous function for 22 bytes

Comment: We need a golfing dialect of Racket, like we need a golfing dialect of [Factor](http://factorcode.org) except people have already made LISPs for golf and the code becomes mostly parentheses.

Comment: I forgot that anonymous functions are generally okay. We definitely could use a lovely LISP for golfing. But yeah, I can only imagine the parens are still going to reduce competitiveness.

Answer (score 2):

## Factor, <s>14</s> 10 bytes

```
1 over / ^
```

Expects input on top of the stack.

Answer (score 2):

### Convex, 3 bytes

Convex is a new language that I am developing that is heavily based on CJam and Golfscript. The interpreter and IDE can be found [here](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex). Input is an integer into the command line arguments. Indexes are one-based. Uses the CP-1252 encoding. This answer in non-competing as it was created after this challenge.

```
_¹#
```

Explanation:

```
    Implied input
_   Duplicate top of stack
 ¹  Find reciprocal
  # Power
    Implied output
```

Comment: Can be found... where?

Comment: @cat oops. Fixed. Note that I literally just updated the interpreter though, but this still works.

Answer (score 2):

## Brachylog, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

Thanks to Fatalize for saving a byte.

```
^?^-1=.
```

### Explanation

```
^?^-1=.
     =.   unify output with
^?^-1     input raised to the 1/input power
```

Comment: You can save one byte: you don't need the first `?`, it is implicitely the current variable at the beginning of the predicate.

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, 20

```
n=(...)print(n^n^-1)
```

How it works:

```
n=(...)              Take input and store at n
       print(
             n^n^-1  n^(n^(-1))
                   )
```

Answer (score 2):

## Quetzalcoatl, 4 bytes

```
c.I?
```

Explanation:

```
c    # Input
 .   # Duplicate
  I  # Inverse
   ? # Power
```

Comment: So... "Quetzalcoatl" can have an operator which finds x^x^-1...

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ What operator are you referring to?

Comment: Like Python's `a**a**-1`.

Answer (score 2):

## dc, <s>8</s> 6 chars

Outputs to the top of the stack:

```
?d1r/^
```

Or if I can expect the input at the top of the stack, this 5 char solution works too:

```
d1r/^
```

Explanation:

```
?        take input from STDIN and execute it (numbers are executed by pushing to the stack)
 d1r     duplicate top of stack, push 1 and swap them
    /^   divide and exponentiate
```

Alas, `dc` does not allow for fractional exponents so this answer does not actually work for any given inputs above 1, and gives the wrong answer for 0 < input < 1. It does the same thing as many of the other programs though.

Answer (score 2):

**Python 3: 34**

```
n=complex(input());print(n**(1/n))
```

Unless I'm missing something this would do nicely. I like that Python normally uses spaces, but this solution doesn't need them.

Comment: Why the `int(`...`)`?

Comment: Python 3 won't implicitly take an input as an integer. So it needs to be converted for the arithmetic in the second statement. Unless it does work for this scenarios in which case my solution will be shorter

Comment: OP: *for any number in your language's domain*

Comment: @Adám I'm not sure that I understand that part then. I just thought it meant it would take any number in the normal base. For Python that is base 10.

Comment: If Python natively handles real numbers, then input may be a real (i.e. non-integer).

Comment: @Adám oh of course. Well in that case as all integers are floats, but not all floats are integers. I can expect a float input

Comment: Doesn't Python handle complex numbers [as well](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Data_Types)?

Comment: Yeah, complex, +4 BYTES NOW!!!!!!!

Comment: @Adám The output will be different.

Comment: wow I didn't know Python could handle complex numbers. @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ what do I need to change. If I change float to complex the code no longer works?

Comment: @george If you want to handle complex (like `3+1j` or `7j`) numbers, simply replace `float` with `complex`. The result of `complex(17)` will be `(17+0j)`, while `complex(11j)` results in `11j`. Note that `11` is an `int`, while `11j` and `(11+2j)` are both `complex`. You can easily replace `(1+2j)` with `1+2j`.

Comment: Ah I did try that, but in my maths classes I use "i" as the imaginary number and I tried this and it chucked an error

Comment: @george It's not `14i`, it's `14j`.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ sorry my last post was clear. I meant when I first tried using complex I got an error because I had used 14i but when you posted afterwards explains it with "j" I figured that was what it was. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
Dzm
```

Explanation:

```
D    # Duplicate the input
 z   # Inverse, 1 ÷ input
  m  # Power, calculating input ** (1 ÷ input)
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RHpt&input=LTAuNQ).

Comment: Wait a minute! If it couldn't parse floats, then floats were not in the domain, and so an integer solution was acceptable.

Comment: @Adám Oh, I didn't know that! The code would still be the same though :p.

Comment: Weird how -.2 still returns -3124.999999999999

Comment: And, also, I think he meant you can remove the non-competing tag.

Comment: @carusocomputing Hmm, how is that weird then?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, python does the same; I thought Python was evaluating at -3125, but it isn't.

Comment: `zm` works now.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 4 bytes

```
Ans^Ansֿ ¹
```

Since TI-Basic is tokenized, this code is a mere four bytes.

Comment: We already have [a TI-BASIC answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73977/39462) at 3 bytes.

Comment: Is `ans` accepted as input method?

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 9 bytes

```
:?a^(1/a)
```

Gets a numeric input from the command line and does the math...

Answer (score 1):

## [Mouse-2002](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse2002), 13 bytes

```
x:x.b/x.&ROOT
```

Other programs assume the number's on the top of the stack and so shall I.

```
x:    ~ put TOS in x
x.    ~ push x
b /   ~ divide by 1
x.    ~ push x again
&ROOT ~ y to the x root
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 33 bytes

```
def f=(x:Double)=>Math.pow(x,1/x)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 11 bytes

Added 2 bytes for `-pn`.

```
$_**=1/$_
```

[Try it here !](https://ideone.com/FLtVGl)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 1 byte

```
@
```

Pyth takes implicit input, so `@` is really equivalent to `@QQ`, where `Q` is the evaluated input.

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40&input=2&debug=0)

Comment: [Test suite (with complex numbers)](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=%40&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=-1%0A-0.2%0A-0.5%0A0.5%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A100%0A10000%0A-2%0A1j%0A2j%0A1%2B2j%0A2%2B2j&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## Mumps, 14 Bytes

```
R I W I**(1/I)
```

R reads from input into variable I, and the W (write) statement does the mathematical calculations.

I will warn you: the output will be ugly as there are no implied newlines in Mumps, and at least the way I read the challenge, the OP didn't require them. If you did want cleaner output, add 2 bytes and add a newline:

```
R I W !,I**(1/I)
```

Answer (score 1):

### SQL (MySQL), 60 bytes

```
CREATE FUNCTION G(X REAL) RETURNS REAL RETURN POWER(X,1./X);
```

Caps lock is cruise control for <s>cool</s> golf.

Comment: Can you do `)RETURNS` instead of `) RETURNS` for -1 byte?

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ Possibly; I don't have a MySQL server handy right now to test it, though.

Answer (score 1):

## Desmos, 14 bytes

```
a=1
\sqrt[a]{a}
```

[Demonstration](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ghpmbwkkyc)

Comment: That looks interesting. So \sqrt is a root-of function, and *not* square-root?

Comment: @Adám It is TeX. `\sqrt` is the Square Root symbol, and the brackets change the root.

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, 23

I post two approaches which occupy the exact same number of bytes.

```
puts [expr $n**(1./$n)]
```

—

```
puts [expr $n**$n**-1.]
```

Available to test on http://rextester.com/EMW19680

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 18 bytes

```
INPUT X?POW(X,1/X)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 24 bytes

```lisp
(lambda(x)(expt x(/ x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc5BDsIgEIXhvaeY5cxCpBgPhAgJCaVoMZnbY9qVi1fd/vnyZkLJaxu8xv6kxOldQ89LHVz8fH94VuGorZPyhVREhsiJ2yvXvltfCiU6O1gnWA3GBmpzQxVSNLv9vmnAr3DY2oMMO4dlbiUq2YMjX8D9BtM/4HYwPg)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 10 bytes

```
=A1^(1/A1)
```

Self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
Ėe
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C4%96e&inputs=3&header=&footer=)

The `e`s are coming!

```
 e # x to the power of
Ė  # 1/x
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 9 bytes

```julia
~x=x^x^-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZJBboMwEEX3nGKWQcF0xpjAhqqLbnqGKJFQIZJLAhGkEt1k1UVP0Sv0TrkI9ThAsBcWfv/7zwzw8XnUOfXDcO2zft/vBQ23n1/I4K0@eK/6/aKbOm912Rm0tWDlAS9BZsueAcZTwFhgKGcsIpLxhOOlG5TF4GBz9e42y8kGmvAjm0JFasK377@loGYhcrC8Y0JcYFQJYwNdjKaoH4wDC7lGfXJ6MiMlmJA@2VArLlQeMUxZnY7GJZcuGeIm4hAV2wxay0cFClOJRqQ0UpzhgXTlOIlZRoz48qNPeuKPN9rMYzCWhnk2DBg4PrQjLIB938IFcw0rCO7GSOj5O8/bwkvedWV7Ad3l53Pb9KtiW@0CuFYBtJfmmG18ODQtFKBrcH4qphXTqvzqVoW/G/4B)

This solution handles both complex numbers and infinities.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
zm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/Kvf/f0MDIAAA)

```
zm  # full program
    # implicit input...
 m  # to the power of...
z   # 1 divided by...
    # implicit input
    # implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ị*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWSx7u7tJaUpyUXAwVWLBE10DPCMIGAA)

`Ị` calculates the reciprocal, and `*` does exponentiation.