# Reciprocal of a number (1/x)

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

### Challenge

Given a (floating-point/decimal) number, return its reciprocal, i.e. 1 divided by the number. The output must be a floating-point/decimal number, not just an integer.

#### Detailed specification

- You must receive input in the form of a floating-point/decimal number...

  - ...which has at least 4 significant digits of precision (if needed).
  - More is better, but does not count in the score.
- You must output, with any acceptable output method...

  - ...the reciprocal of the number.
  - This can be defined as 1/x, x⁻¹.
  - You must output with at least 4 significant digits of precision (if needed).

Input will be positive or negative, with absolute value in the range [0.0001, 9999] inclusive. You will never be given more than 4 digits past the decimal point, nor more than 4 starting from the first non-zero digit. Output needs to be accurate up to the 4th digit from the first non-zero one.

(Thanks @MartinEnder)

Here are some sample inputs:

```
0.5134
0.5
2
2.0
0.2
51.2
113.7
1.337
-2.533
-244.1
-0.1
-5
```

Note that you will never be given inputs which have above 4 digits of precision.

Here is a sample function in Ruby:

```
def reciprocal(i)
    return 1.0 / i
end
```

### Rules

- All accepted forms of output are allowed
- Standard loopholes banned
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer in bytes wins, but will not be selected.

#### Clarifications

- You will never receive the input `0`.

### Bounties

This challenge is obviously trivial in most languages, but it can offer a fun challenge in more esoteric and unusual languages, so some users are willing to award points for doing this in unusually difficult languages.

- <s>[@DJMcMayhem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31716/djmcmayhem) will award a **+150 points** bounty to the shortest brain-flak answer, since brain-flak is notoriously difficult for floating-point numbers</s>
- [@L3viathan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21173/l3viathan) will award a **+150 points** bounty to the shortest [OIL](https://github.com/L3viathan/OIL) answer. OIL has no native floating point type, nor does it have division.
- [@Riley](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/57100/riley) will award a **+100 points** bounty to the shortest sed answer.
- [@EriktheOutgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer) will award a **+100 points** bounty to the shortest Sesos answer. Division in brainfuck derivatives such as Sesos is very difficult, let alone floating-point division.
- <s>I ([@Mendeleev](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53551/Mendeleev)) will award a bounty of **+100 points** to the shortest Retina answer.</s>

If there's a language you think would be fun to see an answer in, and you're willing to pay the rep, feel free to add your name into this list (sorted by bounty amount)

### Leaderboard

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=114544,OVERRIDE_USER=62393;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={};e.forEach(function(e){var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text().toLowerCase()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link,uniq:o}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.uniq>s.uniq?1:e.uniq<s.uniq?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=617d0685f6f3"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Please [stop upvoting trivial answers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10132/41805)

Comment: @KritixiLithos People can vote as they see fit. Given the simplicity of this challenge, *most*, if not *all* answers are something like `1/x`.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere ...until people have had enough time to implement the reciprocal in languages without floating point numbers and/or division.

Comment: This isn't objectively specified without very clear detail on accuracy and precision.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Different languages implement floating point numbers very differently. I can't think of a good way to write a spec. I would really appreciate help.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73920/golf-the-x%E1%B5%97%CA%B0-root-of-x)

Comment: Regarding sed and Retina, there is a meta [consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5349/59010) that the input can be in unary. For floating point input I guess '3.5' can be given as '000.00000'. Do you allow it?

Comment: @MartinEnder What I am saying is using most languages make the answer "uninteresting", but in any other language, the answer is bounty-worthy.

Comment: @seshoumara How would you enter 3.1415 in unary?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma `000.<1415 zeroes>`

Comment: @seshoumara I guess... Would make it uninteresting though. I would prefer the (much harder) decimal alternative

Comment: What about `3.05` then? That needs to be distinguishable for `3.5`, they can’t both be `000.00000`.

Comment: @Lynn idea: the part after the decimal is reversed. So `3.5` is `000.00000`, `1.15` is `0.0<51 zeroes>`, `3.05` is `000.<50 zeroes>`

Comment: @ГригорийПерельман That is interesting, but now the point of saving bytes is defeated, so I might as well take the input in decimal, as the OP prefers.

Comment: So how exactly does the input format work for very large or small numbers? Do we assume that there's always a `.` somewhere, at least one digit before and one digit after, and we ignore the exact value of all digits past the fourth from the first non-zero one? So input `123400.0` would be treated identically to `123456.78`?

Comment: And then can we assume that we'll always do get 4 significant digits? I.e. can we assume that `12.3` won't be given as input, but at least `12.30` instead?

Comment: @MartinEnder No

Comment: @MartinEnder  All numbers you will be given are 4 significant or less. they can be given in `0.x`, `x`, `x.y`, but not `x.0` or `.x`

Comment: What about accuracy? Presumably you want 4 sf of accuracy too, but then there's the issue of [rounding](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5608/194). Floating point questions are hard to get right and very worth [sandboxing](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/194).

Comment: @MendeleevLemon Don't be so stringent on input format. A language can have different data types, making `x` an integer, and `x.0` a decimal/float. A language should be able to use its native representation of a floating point number, if it has one.

Comment: This is still *really* underspecified and shouldn't have been re-opened.

Comment: @MendeleevLemon Can we choose how to round?

Comment: @MendeleevLemon May the output have leading zeroes? (e.g. `000.3333` or `024.424`)

Comment: @MartinEnder Please clarify.

Comment: @L3viathan Yes.

Comment: @MendeleevLemon Can we e.g. choose to round 0.12345 as 0.1234?

Comment: Can we have our input padded with extra zeros.  E.g. instead of 5 we take 5.00000 as input?

Comment: @L3viathan Sure, I guess

Comment: @WheatWizard Yeah

Comment: -1, this is a poor challenge because using a builtin is the ONLY way to do it and know you have satisfied the "specification". If you have a standard floating point implementation, you can use it and tell yourself this is standard floating point, it must be ok. If you have to implement it yourself, there is no specification so you can't sensibly try to golf it.

Comment: Can we output results below `1` as `.123` (i.e. without the leading zero)?

Comment: Can scientific notation be used for output?

Comment: As a bonus, your title contains a huge part of the solution for dozens of languages.

Comment: Can we round the answer? Say for input `11` we output `.090909091`

Comment: @KritixiLithos Sure...

Comment: Those bounties are not able to be given. You cannot do arbitrary amounts repeatedly. You can do 50, 100, 200, 400 then 500

Comment: Can we output with trailing zeroes? For example, outputting `.5000000000` for input `2`

Comment: @Tim I believe that is only the case for a single user.  Separate users can bounty how they see fit.

Comment: @MartinEnder Yes

Comment: Argh, all the languages on bounty has no division at all!

Comment: @SIGSEGV That's precisely why there are bounties for these languages

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Your bounty can now be assigned

Comment: And what has to happen with input 0.0000001?

Comment: @RosLuP 4 significant digits\, that input will never occur because it is basically 0

Comment: I'm assuming that fraction number formats cannot be outputted?

Answer (score 58):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>772</s> <s>536</s> <s>530</s> <s>482</s> 480 + 1 = 481 bytes

Since Brain-Flak does not support floating point numbers I had to use the `-c` flag in order input and output with strings, hence the +1.

```
(({})[((((()()()()())){}{})){}{}]){((<{}>))}{}({}<{({}[((((()()()){}())()){}{}){}]<>)<>}<>{({}<>[()()])<>}{}([]<{({}<>[()()])<>}>)<>([[]](())){({}()<((((((({}<(((({})({})){}{}){}{})>)({})){}{}){})({})){}{}){})>)}{}({}(<>))<>([()]{()<(({})){({}[()])<>}{}>}{}<><{}{}>){({}<((()()()()()){})>(<>))<>([()]{()<(({})){({}[()])<>}{}>}{}<><([{}()]{})>)}{}<>({}()<<>([]){{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>){({}[()]<({}<>((((()()()){}){}){}){})<>>)}{}([()()])([]){{}({}<>((((()()()){}){}){}){})<>([])}<>>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#lVBBDsMwCPuOOXTqbRfERyJO2y@ivL0z0GzNpB2WtlQB23F8AH1IQyyZj0gf7GZ16YD2YSLcEayd5UIgigUnhwQ1URtqgVNrgfHoENdcv7sBRmvuyHMRaopaRNZPMO1UsaWxbuz0CfpIbR7UUzNRaX4aik9Ng2o50iWGUPtDBi3M@/RAUl4myEyxwqvres3traM5W0L9vAHM9Cq0q9pPRp4RxOPY7rd9P7bn4wU)

## Explanation

The first thing we need to take care of is the negative case.  Since the reciprocal of a negative number is always negative we can simply hold on to the negative sign until the end.  We start by making a copy of the top of the stack and subtracting 45 (the ASCII value of `-`) from it.  If this is one we put a zero on the top of the stack, if not we do nothing.  Then the we pick up the top of the stack to be put down at the end of the program.  If the input started with a `-` this is still a `-` however if it is *not* we end up picking up that zero we placed.

```
(({})[((((()()()()())){}{})){}{}]){((<{}>))}{}
({}<
```

Now that that is out of the way we need to convert the ASCII realizations of each digit into there actual values (0-9).  We also are going to remove the decimal point `.` to make computations easier.  Since we need to know where the decimal point started when we reinsert it later we store a number to keep track of how many digits were in front of the `.` on the offstack.

Here is how the code does that:

We start by subtracting 46 (the ASCII value of `.`) from each element on the stack (simultaneously moving them all onto the offstack).  This will make each digit two more than should be but will make the `.` exactly zero.

```
{({}[((((()()()){}())()){}{}){}]<>)<>}<>
```

Now we move everything onto the left stack until we hit a zero (subtracting two from each digit while we go):

```
{({}<>[()()])<>}{}
```

We record the stack height

```
([]<
```

Move everything else onto the left stack (once again subtracting the last two from every digit as we move them)

```
  {({}<>[()()])<>}
```

And put the stack height we recorded down

```
>)
```

Now we want to combine the digits into a single base 10 number.  We also want to make a power of 10 with twice the digits as that number for use in the calculation.

We start by setting up a 1 on top of the stack to make the power of 10 and pushing the stack height minus one to the on stack for the use of looping.

```
<>([][(())])
```

Now we loop the stack height minus 1 times,

```
{
 ({}[()]<
```

Each time we multiply the top element by 100 and underneath it multiply the next element by 10 and add that to the number below.

```
 ((((((({}<(((({})({})){}{}){}{})>)({})){}{}){})({})){}{}){})
```

We end our loop

```
 >)
}{}
```

Now we are finally done with the set up and can begin the actual calculation.

```
({}(<>))<>([()]{()<(({})){({}[()])<>}{}>}{}<><{}{}>)
```

That was it...

We divide the power of 10 by the modified version of the input using [0 '](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20059/millet-mage)'s integer division algorithm as found on [the wiki](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak/wiki/Basic-Arithmetic-Operations).  This simulates the division of 1 by the input the only way Brain-Flak knows how.

Lastly we have to format our output into the appropriate ASCII.

Now that we have found `ne` we need to take out the `e`.  The first step to this is converting it to a list of digits.  This code is a modified version of [0   '](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20059/)'s [divmod algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114321/56656).

```
{({}<((()()()()()){})>(<>))<>([()]{()<(({})){({}[()])<>}{}>}{}<><([{}()]{})>)}{}
```

Now we take the number and add the decimal point back where it belongs.  Just thinking about this part of the code brings back headaches so for now I will leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out how and why it works.

```
<>({}()<<>([]){{}({}<>)<>([])}{}<>>){({}[()]<({}<>((((()()()){}){}){}){})<>>)}{}([()()])([]){{}({}<>((((()()()){}){}){}){})<>([])}<>
```

Put the negative sign down or a null character if there is no negative sign.

```
>)
```

Comment: +1, I love how much of this explanation is `I don't know what this does or why I need it, but I promise it's important.`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for input `1.0` or `10`

Comment: Can anybody else read this code? Is Brain-Flak meant to be write-only?

Comment: @EricDuminil Brain-flak is an esoteric language so it is very hard to read at a glance.  People who are well versed in Brain-Flak can read it to some degree of fluency.  But this task in incredibly complex and Brain-Flak is not really designed with readability in mind.

Comment: @ThisGuy It requires the `-c` flag to be run with ASCII in and out.  Since Brain-Flak doesn't support floating numbers I need to take IO as a string.

Comment: I was going to do this :( Now I am sad

Answer (score 48):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 10 bytes

```python
1..__div__
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S1OwVYj5b6inFx@fklkWH/@/oCgzr0QjTcNcU/M/AA)

Comment: Dot. Dot. Div. +1 :)

Answer (score 38):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>99</s> 91 bytes

```
1`\.|$
8$*;
+`;(;*)(\d)
$2$1
\d+
$*1,10000000$*
(1+),(\1)+1*
$#2
+`(\d)(;+);
$2$1
1`;
.
;
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#JYu7DcMwEEN7rhEF0Mc@iCcrdnADZAkVKjJGdnfOMIv3WJDP@Jkn55BfwBGyoUyLllMc34SggRjfgpC5sN4JGZElLXEwFWaEh/rp2kcrye4Tp0FgqOdZpbNtcEGhUr0pOh1kkx2U1pzqm1Wlt@baNiHWeqFffh/76w8)

Woohoo, sub-100! This is surprisingly efficient, considering that it creates (and then matches against) a string with more than 10<sup>7</sup> characters at one point. I'm sure it's not optimal yet, but I'm quite happy with the score at the moment.

Results with absolute value less than 1 will be printed without the leading zero, e.g. `.123` or `-.456`.

#### Explanation

The basic idea is to using integer division (because that's fairly easy with regex and unary arithmetic). To ensure that we get a sufficient number of significant digits, we divide the input into **10<sup>7</sup>**. That way, any input up to **9999** still results in a 4-digit number. Effectively, that means we're multiplying the result by **10<sup>7</sup>** so we need to keep track of that when later reinsert the decimal point.

```
1`\.|$
8$*;
```

We start by replacing the decimal point, or the end of the string if there is no decimal point with 8 semicolons. The first one of them is essentially the decimal point itself (but I'm using semicolons because they don't need to be escaped), the other 7 indicate that value has been multiplied by **10<sup>7</sup>** (this isn't the case yet, but we know we will do that later).

```
+`;(;*)(\d)
$2$1
```

We first turn the input into an integer. As long as there are still digits after the decimal point, we move one digit to the front and remove one of the semicolons. This is because moving the decimal point right multiplies the input by **10**, and therefore divides the result by **10**. Due to the input restrictions, we know this will happen at most four times, so there are always enough semicolons to be removed.

```
\d+
$*1,10000000$*
```

Now that the input is an integer, we convert it to unary and append **10<sup>7</sup>** `1`s (separated by a `,`).

```
(1+),(\1)+1*
$#2
```

We divide the integer into **10<sup>7</sup>** by counting how many backreferences to it fit (`$#2`). This is standard unary integer division `a,b` --> `b/a`. Now we just need to correct the position of the decimal point.

```
+`(\d)(;+);
$2$1
```

This is basically the inverse of the second stage. If we still have more than one semicolon, that means we still need to divide the result by **10**. We do this by moving the semicolons one position to the left and dropping one semicolon until we either reach the left end of the number, or we're left with only one semicolon (which is the decimal point itself).

```
1`;
.
```

Now is a good time to turn the first (and possibly only) `;` back into `.`.

```
;
0
```

If there are still semicolons left, we've reached the left end of the number, so dividing by 10 again will insert zeros behind the decimal point. This is easily done by replacing each remaining `;` with a `0`, since they're immediately after the decimal point anyway.

Comment: A very short algorithm, +1. I bet the sed translation would be the shortest as well. Can you replace `\B;` with `^;` to save 1 byte?

Comment: @seshoumara No because of negative inputs, where there's a `-` in front of the `;`.

Answer (score 32):

## [yup](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/yup), 5 bytes

```
|0~-e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/yup#0/pfY1Cnm/pf@f9/3bz/RgA) This takes input from the top of the stack and leaves output on the top of the stack. The TIO link takes input from command line arguments, which is only capable of taking integer input.

### Explanation

yup only has a few operators. The ones used in this answer are **ln**(x) (represented by `|`), **0**() (constant, nilary function returning `0`), **−** (subtraction), and **exp**(x) (represented by `e`). `~` switches the top two members on the stack.

```
|0~-e     top of the stack: n    stack: [n]
|         pop n, push ln(n)      stack: [ln(n)]
 0        push 0                 stack: [ln(n), 0]
  ~       swap                   stack: [0, ln(n)]
   -      subtract               stack: [-ln(n)]
    e     exp                    stack: [exp(-ln(n))]
```

This uses the identity

[image: x/y = e^(ln(x)-ln(y))]

which implies that

[image]

Comment: I'd love to improve my content, so if you'd explain your downvote, that would really help and I would appreciate that :)

Answer (score 20):

## [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/), <s>63</s>, 56 bytes

```
HOW DUZ I r YR n 
VISIBLE QUOSHUNT OF 1 AN n
IF U SAY SO
```

7 bytes saved thanks to @devRicher!

This defines a function 'r', which can be called with:

```
r 5.0
```

or any other `NUMBAR`.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/Gn1P/1)

Comment: I guess you could use `ITZ A NUMBAR` in the assignment of `I`?

Comment: `HOW DUZ I r YR n VISIBLE QUOSHUNT OF 1 AN n IF U SAY SO` (add newlines) is a few bytes shorter and can be called with `r d`, where `d` is any `NUMBAR`.

Comment: You can use `IZ` instead of `DUZ` because of interpreter rule

Answer (score 19):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 575 + 1 (`-r` flag) = <s>723</s> <s>718</s> <s>594</s> <s>588</s> 576 bytes

```sed
s/$/\n0000000000/
tb
:b
s/^0+//
s/\.(.)(.*\n)/\1.\2/
tD
bF
:D
s/.*/&&&&&&&&&&/2m
tb
:F
s/\.//
h
s/\n.+//
s/-//
:
s/\b9/;8/
s/\b8/;7/
s/\b7/;6/
s/\b6/;5/
s/\b5/;4/
s/\b4/;3/
s/\b3/;2/
s/\b2/;1/
s/\b1/;0/
s/\b0//
/[^;]/s/;/&&&&&&&&&&/g
t
y/;/0/
x
G
s/[^-]+(\n0+)\n(0+)/\2\1/
s/\n0+/&&\n./
:a
s/^(-?)(0*)0\n0\2(.*)$/\10\2\n\30/
ta
s/.*/&&&&&&&&&&/2m
s/\n0(0*\n\..*)$/\n\1 x/
Td
s/x//
ta
:d
s/[^-]+\n//
s/-(.+)/\1-/
s/\n//
:x
s/^0{10}/0x/
s/(.)0{10}/0\1/
tx
s/00/2/g
s/22/4/g
y/0/1/
s/41/5/g
s/21/3/g
s/45/9/g
s/44/8/g
s/43/7/g
s/42/6/g
y/ /0/
s/([1-9])0/\1/g
y/x/0/
s/(.+)-/-\1/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#bVG7bhsxEOz3K1wExp2E5ZK8t1ikMZwfSCdKgM4OYhehgpyKM4J8dtooQ65jpDABknO7O3uzw@siHyQm@7aELjPtZlrkaLciuKOpTF2ZTUy1RGeiR8kdzfe0u0PWbOT2bYn/Vuj3hQb2UwbJaCPGucuBeZIwltbzKGFQNEjoFfUSOkWdhFZRK6FR1EjwirwEp8hJsIos/iH7YzjIIuF/ZV/pQi8IoW6lT6jdH/mwrTD6to6pwinRR@2HGKjQDb2n7ETFH@vKbmqLVPTwooZpDjCm2GTLTu85UTqBhiKjlBTdzSr0@RG5VQpv9/hPS0zqUmWyFscqJXu2ltf46ewvsWsO40FeP7PiS87j5TyGXMR7aQFeMGmZpnXSacJJU0DbyaSglVFBI4MCL30h30gxtNo7ng61hZ4SXl/DkMjCCF6v7ExD7PK2xBPxSDwQ98QdcUuMhEeO2OAy@bYdle0IIUeeGmqpo54GGmkitEE3dP1z/n55Pqflyj9@pzM/nB6evvwF)

Note: floats for which the absolute value is less than 1 will have to be written without a leading 0 like `.5` instead of `0.5`. Also the number of decimal places is equal to [image], where `n` is the number of decimal places in the number (so giving `13.0` as input will give more decimal places than giving `13` as input)

This is my first sed submission on PPCG. Ideas for the decimal-to-unary conversion were taken from [this amazing answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51329/41805). Thanks to @seshoumara for guiding me through sed!

This code performs repeated long division to get the result. The division only takes ~150 bytes. The unary-decimal conversions take the most bytes, and a few other bytes go to supporting negative numbers and floating-point inputs

#### Explanation

[Explanation on TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#hVRtb9s2EP5@v@IQD6ucRKIk23mxsA3r3BQG1nTYun2JEoCSGJuITAoindgr@teXHUnbSYABE2zpeOS9PXzungc/d51QDWYppu9Mgl@W0iD97FJgIx9lQ5unOKe1VA9g2HesVOnhYWArgIE3qnqu6iWu9KPYmYtarniLnZbKYoZWe3UvF0sL0woGvwt3GFvBG6kWLj5GZk0@uMH7Xq9QrVeV6A228kFgkk7whx8xTSZDyuMuPWEMBp@cg/8NZliZRMkwSo5LNWRllpQ52c7v/RFeOR9LitkLs26taFAq5EiZ1MKY@3VLYmWstGsrtTrFhXbed@XOwM5gIFoj3uqvoLoiZD6RQ9m12zd4YrUlvAvkrdH4IEQX8Fpp3VD@Rlr5KGA6o7STY/b94WH5ykEtlItU8frhVbjKX8T06gDqWzyMVLVAad3N8rb14Z749g1KqPSTR4pwXR78HK2VEg4H3m@PPAsWxp1SicPfsJjeMPhFq0fRW@dvregkTN2Z6pIVF8xLF6w4D9I5K86CdMaKSZAmrBgHacyKUZBGrMiDlLMiC1LGijRIKYVlN3fFLTOseI3RAixsSZW6tHbcdiX6tHaE2pfdcWtFr9B0vBawgY/k@uYuvj2JiOMnw1JF9GZlXmbO2WCAH65nOAvAxlbHf3qfta/dEDX8mfcfPs6vcUZX7VUw@E3097pfGfxVE8kPG4MrUnKLrdYPBo1eCQ9u4Lp1DRXVXL2zxMqVcFkPp55ARvel2jOpVLVeK1uqQF13EbR0KdletwaX@glXXG1f6NBSqYFuXJknwsIs9bptiP@PosCmcy2WpXcE1EwupDWRGu65YPbxQ3Me2MwDxNQzDS0wdfDu8/nsePeW@6KmWikFrdFQSu0p8nBNPFzEi7n33Acecvxb9DpE9jVTVlIZsTvTCe7bnO6N2EDsZDDlbkxE8U/DKD0eprRV5jQBhjTBMhJLVY7c/OL/1WbeE5nRoSSYqDLDDYMvDe1tmLd7ocT8r/kf88/Xr@7fU8NxZEeX1yyBabMnWqlCE0WJI1oWe3Ir31JHNe@JXVR7fxQTMQoagIcnDEKYbvwk/Jql31i6ccY05XZLR1q7edWbgtOc6LjsUd/v2iE1u1YgZXNIlMAVfcd76xqdZnxOTWVYnrMxCVvqLN@N44xNwkbGRl4YT9hlEMbsIggjdh6EnJ15Y2S@gaObLL68HaZUs1dvdmqCIWYxKZ@f4ywZQZylEF9CfAHxOcRnEE8gHkNMGzntQZzQJ3HfdAL@nwGpMshhBGOYwBmcwwVcArkhd//ozk1w8xz3/wI)

```sed
#Append 10 0's. This is the dividend, I think
s/$/\n0000000000/
tb

#This branch moves the decimal point 1 to the right
:b
#Remove leading 0's (such as from numbers like .05 => 0.5)
s/^0+//
#Move the decimal point 1 to the right
s/\.(.)(.*\n)/\1.\2/
#If the above has resulted in a successful substitution, go to branch D
tD
#else go to branch F
bF

#Multiply the dividend by 10; also keeps the mood positive
:D
s/.*/&&&&&&&&&&/2m
#Then go back to branch b
tb

:F
#Remove decimal point since it is all the way to the right now
s/\.//
h
#Remove "unnecessary" things
s/\n.+//
s/-//

#Convert to unary
:
s/\b9/;8/
s/\b8/;7/
s/\b7/;6/
s/\b6/;5/
s/\b5/;4/
s/\b4/;3/
s/\b3/;2/
s/\b2/;1/
s/\b1/;0/
s/\b0//
/[^;]/s/;/&&&&&&&&&&/g
t
y/;/0/

#Append the unary number to the pattern space
x
G
s/[^-]+(\n0+)\n(0+)/\2\1/

### END Decimal-to-Unary conversion
### BEGIN Division

#Performs Long Division
#Format looks something like this (can't remember): divisor\ndividend\ncount\nresult
#Count controls how many decimal places the answer should have; dp => 10^numDigits(n)
#Removes divisor from dividend and then add a 0 to result
#Once the dividend becomes too small, append a space to result and remove a zero from count
#Rinse and repeat
s/\n0+/&&\n./
:a
s/^(-?)(0*)0\n0\2(.*)$/\10\2\n\30/
ta
s/.*/&&&&&&&&&&/2m
s/\n0(0*\n\..*)$/\n\1 x/
Td
s/x//
ta

### END DIVISION
### BEGIN Unary-to-Decimal conversion

:d
s/[^-]+\n//
s/-(.+)/\1-/
s/\n//

#"carry over"-ing; .0000000000 => 0.
:x
s/^0{10}/0x/
s/(.)0{10}/0\1/
tx

#Convert each pair of unary 0s to their decimal counterparts
s/00/2/g
s/22/4/g
y/0/1/
s/41/5/g
s/21/3/g
s/45/9/g
s/44/8/g
s/43/7/g
s/42/6/g
y/ /0/
s/([1-9])0/\1/g
y/x/0/
s/(.+)-/-\1/
```

#### Edits

- `s:s/(.)/(.)/g:y/\1/\2/g:g` to save 1 byte at each substitution (5 in total)
- Saved a ton of bytes by looking at a nice decimal-to-unary converter on "Tips for golfing in sed"
- I changed around some substitutions revolved around taking care of the minus sign to save 6 bytes.
- Used `\n` instead of `;` as the separator, then I was able to shorten the "multiply by 10" substitutions to save 12 bytes (thanks to @Riley and @seshoumara for showing me this)

Comment: You made it! +1

Answer (score 18):

## [OIL](https://github.com/L3viathan/OIL), <s>1428</s> 1420 bytes

Oh well. I thought I might as well try it, and I did in the end succeed. There's just one downside: It takes almost as long to run as it took to write.

The program is separated into multiple files, which have all 1-byte-filenames (and count for one additional byte in my byte calculation). Some of the files are part of the example files of the OIL language, but there's no real way to consistently call them (there's no search path or anything like that in OIL yet, so I don't consider them a standard library), but that also means that (at the time of posting) some of the files are more verbose than neccessary, but usually only by a few bytes.

The computations are accurate to 4 digits of precision, but calculating even a simple reciprocal (such as the input `3`) takes a really long time (over 5 minutes) to complete. For testing purposes, I've also made a minor variant that's accurate to 2 digits, which takes only a few seconds to run, in order to prove that it does work.

I'm sorry for the huge answer, I wish I could use some kind of spoiler tag. I could also put the bulk of it on gist.github.com or something similar, if desired.

Here we go: `main`, 217 bytes (file name doesn't count for bytes):

```
5
1
1
4
-
14
a
5
Y
10
5
8
14
29
12
1
97
1
97
24
9
24
13
99

1
1
4
31
1
35

14
a
32
.
10
32
8
50
41
1
53
2
14
b
1
1
6
72
14
c
5
0000
14
d
6
6
10
74
5
63
68
1
6
1
6
72
14
b
1
5
1
77
0
14
e
1
0
14
f
1
1
1
31
0
14
b
0
0
4
```

`a` (checks if a given string is in a given other string), 74+1 = 75 bytes:

```
5
0
5
1
14
g
2
0
10
2
30
24
13
10
1
31
27
18
14
h
1
1
6
4
4
30
3
4
29
N
Y
```

`b` (joins two given strings), 20+1=21 bytes:

```
5
0
5
1
13
0
2
0
4
0
```

`c` (given a symbol, splits the given string at its first occurrence), 143+1=144 bytes (this one is obviously still golfable):

```
5
0
5
83
12
83
83





10
84
0
21
17
8
13
6
12
1
13
1
1
5
2
14
i
45
1
1
83
1
1
45
2
14
i
57
1
9
45
13
84

1



8
13
1
13
56
13
13

2
4
1
11
4
2
```

`d` (given a string, gets the first 4 characters), 22+1=23 bytes:

```
5
0
12
0
20
13
21
4

4
```

`e` (high-level division (but with zero division danger)), 138+1=139 bytes:

```
5
0
5
1
.
.
1
1
6
14
j
0
0
1
0
4
10
11
1
58
21
14
b
4
4
1
1
15
14
k
0
15
1
6
1
14
j
0
0
1
0
5
14
b
4
4
9
8
10
8
11
58
53
10
11
1
58
25
4
4
```

`f` (moves a dot 4 positions to the right; "divides" by 10000), 146+1=147 bytes:

```
5
.
12
0
100
10
101
1
14
10
8
6
6
5
1
6
34
1
6
33
8
33
1
6
37
8
37
10
55
3
48
32
1
102
101
1
1
102
9
55
8
34
8
33
8
37
6
27
1
100
53
13
101


4

4
```

`g` (checks if a string starts with a given character), 113+1=114 bytes:

```
5
0
5
1
12
0
100
12
1
200
1
6
2
1
9
3
8
2
8
3
9
100
9
200
1
2
31
1
3
32
10


39
35
4
38
3
N
10
100
5
44
16
4
46
Y
```

`h` (returns everything but the first character of a given string), 41+1=42 bytes:

```
5
0
12
0
100
9
100
1
100
12
13
102

0
4
0
```

`i` (subtracts two numbers), 34+1=35 bytes:

```
5
0
5
1
10
16
1
14
9
9
0
9
1
6
4
0
```

`j` (low-level division that doesn't work in all cases), 134+1=135 bytes:

```
5
0
5
2
10
2
19
52
9
1
2
3
10
23
2
28
17
10
23
0
35
22
9
0
9
2
6
12
8
1
1
3
2
6
17
10
23
2
46
40
9
2
9
3
6
35
4
1
11
4
3
3
4
19
11
4
0
```

`k` (multiplication), 158+1=159 bytes:

```
5
0
5
1
8
0
9
0
8
1
9
1
1
5
2
12
0
68
10
69
66
23
29
8
7
14
l
0
0
12
1
68
10
69
66
37
43
8
7
14
l
1
1
10
0
5
56
48
9
0
14
m
2
1
6
43
10
7
3
61
63
4
66
4
2
3
-
```

`l` (return absolute value), 58+1=59 bytes:

```
5
-
12
0
24
10
25
1
13
10
4
0
3
9
24
1
24
20
13
26

0
6
10
```

`m` (addition), 109+1=110 bytes:

```
5
0
5
1
8
0
9
0
8
1
9
1
12
1
46
10
47
45
31
20
10
1
43
42
25
9
1
8
0
6
20
10
1
43
42
36
8
1
9
0
6
31
4
0
3
-
```

Answer (score 16):

### J, 1 byte

```
%
```

`%` is a function giving the reciprocal of its input. You can run it like this

```
   % 2
0.5
```

Answer (score 16):

## Vim, <s>10</s> 8 bytes/keystrokes

```
C<C-r>=1/<C-r>"
```

Since V is backwards compatible, you may [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@@9s46xbZGdrqA@mlbj@/zfVM/ivWwYA)

Comment: @NonlinearFruit No, it didn't. Turns out, I was overthinking it, and supporting that is actually *less* bytes, not more. Thanks!

Comment: This is really interesting. I wonder if it's possible to do the same thing without using the `=`. Solely relying on other macros, registers for holding memory, and keys to navigate and modify data. Would be much more complex but I think it would be so cool! I think `f` would play a huge role as a conditional test.

Comment: If input is 6431, the output should be 0.0001554, or more precise, but not 0.

Comment: @seshoumara I think you need to input `6431.0` so it's treated as a floating point number

Comment: @Poke I tried it and it works, but the output is in scientific notation. Is that allowed?

Comment: @seshoumara I don't see anything against it and it does still have 4 significant figures. I'll ask in a comment

Answer (score 16):

## [JSFuck](http://www.jsfuck.com), 3320 bytes

JSFuck is an esoteric and educational programming style based on the atomic parts of JavaScript. It uses only six different characters `()[]+!` to write and execute code.

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[+[]])+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+(![]+[+![]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]]
```

#### Try it online!

```js
alert(
  /* empty array       */ []
  /* ['fill']          */ [(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]]
  /* ['constructor']   */ [([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]
  /* ('return+1/this') */ ((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[+[]])+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+(![]+[+![]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])
  /* ['call']          */ [([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]]
  (prompt())
)
```

Comment: This language-subset is hard to golf by hand but easy to automate (as a conversion from ordinary JavaScript).

Comment: True, but the character count of the source doesn't directly relate to the output length.

Comment: I was trying to convey that, if you have a source, it's easier to automate the golfy conversion than do a golfy version by hand.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Even when it's automated, it's also tricky to find out which "core" JavaScript code actually produces the shortest program. In this particular case, `return 1/this` would be about 76 bytes longer than `return+1/this`.

Comment: `[].fill.constructor('alert(1/prompt())')` 2929 bytes https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5vGTqw4TQQ/  add `()` 2931

Answer (score 16):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 467 bytes

```
Go to Starchild Numerology:w 1 l 2 r 1 l 1 l 2 l.1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.Go to Post Office:w 1 r 2 r 1 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:s 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.Go to Divide and Conquer:e 4 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:e 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:e 1 l 1 r.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/taxi#rVDNCoJAEH6V7wkEq5PHCrqVUC@w6bgObbs1uyY@vZVKRElBdJphhu@3XTkEh21QkpVscqyrI4kzTjdJjRgGE0g3@91EMdijVhzYaqgwCo1Szg7VCQon5T1ZTQLt7oCb1pIvnBOUzbFw9lyRRL2J1PmATVFwRp22DNqd/kfKXUmYqz2Zgn1J0gyEr@fED0nkN4Pvj4Qw@5M3@urrqZ@RxuiRrW2nVw)

Ungolfed:

```
Go to Starchild Numerology:west 1 left, 2 right, 1 left, 1 left, 2 left.
1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.
Go to Post Office:west 1 right, 2 right, 1 right, 1 left.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery:south 1 left, 1 right.
Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.
Go to Divide and Conquer:east 4 left.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery:east 1 right.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office:east 1 left, 1 right.
```

Comment: Would you mind adding a non-golfed version for easier readability?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Sure, it's just that when I answered this it was late night.

Answer (score 11):

## C, <s>15</s> 12 bytes

```
#define f 1/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@6@ckpqWmZeqkKZgqP8/M69EITcxM09Dk6uaSwEICoqAQmkaSqppSjoKaRrGegaamtZctf8B)

**<s>16</s> 13 bytes, if it needs to handle integer input also:**

```
#define f 1./
```

So you can call it with `f(3)` instead of `f(3.0)`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@6@ckpqWmZeqkKZgqKf/PzOvRCE3MTNPQ5OrmksBCAqKgEJpGkqqaUo6Cmkaxpqa1ly1/wE)

*Thanks to @hvd for golfing 3 bytes!*

Comment: The original version of your program has been lost to the consecutive-edit merger, so the ---17--- is a little meaningless.

Comment: Could you change the language name to "C Preprocessor?"

Comment: Being very picky, this doesn't "compute" the value; it just replaces `f(x)` with `1/x`. When the "function" is executed, which can happen as late as runtime or as early as your compiler feels like (and can prove correct), is _technically_ not the preprocessor step.

Comment: Also this won't work if x is an expression that includes other operators (e.g. `5+3`)

Comment: @fluffy That's not relevant.

Comment: It doesn't work with integer inputs, however.

Comment: @pipe It doesn't need to work with integer inputs. From the question: "Given a (floating-point/decimal) number"

Comment: @Steadybox It's also clear from the examples that `2` and `-5` are a valid inputs, which will be treated as an integers here.

Comment: @pipe That's because they are integer literals. Using `2.0` and `-5.0` instead will work.

Comment: @Steadybox I'm literally quoting from the _sample input_ section in the challenge description. Your code _will_ get `2` and `-5` as input. Both `2` and `-5` are decimals, containing digits in the range 0 to 9.

Comment: There is no need for a function-like macro: `#define f 1./` works too.

Comment: "Being very picky, this doesn't "compute" the value; it just replaces f(x) with 1/x."  I'm that picky.  This is entirely possible to do using the C preprocessor, but one shouldn't claim to have done something in the C preprocessor if one requires C or C++ to actually do it.

Comment: @HWalters That's why the language name in the answer originally was C, not C preprocessor. I think I'll change it back.

Answer (score 11):

## x86_64 Linux machine language, 5 bytes

```
0:       f3 0f 53 c0             rcpss  %xmm0,%xmm0
4:       c3                      retq
```

To test this, you can compile and run the following C program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
const char f[]="\xf3\xf\x53\xc0\xc3";
int main(){
  for( float i = .1; i < 2; i+= .1 ) {
    printf( "%f %f\n", i, ((float(*)(float))f)(i) );
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#PYvBCsIwEETv@YohUshqKWrx1NYfsR5C6tJAm0gaoSD99poqeBjezrBv3Vlnhlf3qKfYWV/0V/FfRh37bTDeTRGm1wF8uzeynblMaedLgjmmlLIS1kWM2jpFbwGwDwo8eB1h0aA4VYk1zgmHrYKwvQHPkERWkBkj49bJHDaHUl9X7el3EDEpS6AqSYtY1vUD)

Comment: We might want to add that `rcpss` only calculates an approximate reciprocal (around 12 bit precision). +1

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@1/1/78pAA)

```
z # pop a  push 1 / a
```

Answer (score 9):

## MATLAB / Octave, 4 bytes

```
@inv
```

Creates a function handle (named `ans`)  to the built-in [`inv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html) function

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/F9NFL4)

Answer (score 8):

### [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>377</s> 362 + 1(r flag) = 363 bytes

**Warning:** the program will eat all the system memory trying to run and require more time to finish than you'd be willing to wait! See below for an explanation and a fast, but less precise, version.

```sed
s:\.|$:,,,,,,,,:;:i;s:,(,+)(\w):\2\1:;ti
h;:;s:\w::2g;y:9876543210:87654321\t :;/ /!s:,:@,:;/\s/!t;x;s:-?.::;x;G;s:,.*::m;s:\s::g;/\w/{s:@+:&&&&&&&&&&:;t}
/@,-?@/!{s:^:10000000,:;h;t}
:l;s:(@+)(,-?\1):\2;:;tl;s:,::;s:@+;?@+::
s:-?:&0:;:c;s:\b9+:0&:;s:.9*;:/&:;h;s:.*/::;y:0123456789:1234567890:;x;s:/.*::;G;s:\n::;s:;::;/;/tc
:f;s:(\w)(,+),:\2\1:;tf;s:,:.:;y:,:0:
```

This is based on the [Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114630/59010) by Martin Ender. I count `\t` from line 2 as a literal tab (1 byte).

My main contribution is to the conversion method from decimal to plain unary (line 2), and vice versa (line 5). I managed to significantly reduce the size of code needed to do this (by ~40 bytes combined), compared to the methods shown in a previous [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51329/59010). I created a [separate tip answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115617/59010) with the details, where I provide ready to use snippets. Because 0 is not allowed as input, a few more bytes were saved.

**Explanation:** to better understand the division algorithm, read the Retina answer first

The program is theoretically correct, the reason why it consumes so much computational resources is that the division step is run hundred of thousands of times, more or less depending on the input, and the regex used gives rise to a backtracking nightmare. The fast version reduces the precision (hence the number of division steps), and changes the regex to reduce the backtracking.

Unfortunately, sed doesn't have a method to directly count how many times a backreference fits into a pattern, like in Retina.

```
s:\.|$:,,,,,,,,:             # replace decimal point or end of string with 8 commas
:i                           # loop to generate integer (useful for unary division)
  s:,(,+)(\w):\2\1:          # move 1 digit in front of commas, and delete 1 comma
ti                           # repeat (':i')
h;:                          # backup pattern and start decimal to unary conversion
  s:\w::2g                   # delete decimal digits, except the first (GNU magic)
  y:9876543210:87654321\t :; # transliterate characters
  / /!s:,:@,:                # if no space is present, append a unary digit ('@')
  /\s/!t                     # if no whitespace is present, go back to ':'
  x;s:-?.::;x                # delete first digit and the negative sign from backup
  G;s:,.*::m;s:\s::g         # append backup, delete whitespace and duplicate stuff
/\w/{s:@+:&&&&&&&&&&:        # if decimal digit left, multiply unary number by 10
t}                           # and repeat (':')
/@,-?@/!{                    # if only one unary number found (the input)
  s:^:10000000,:             # prepend decimal 10^7 separated by a comma
h;t}                         # backup pattern and convert new number to unary also
:l                           # start unary division loop (tons of RAM and time!!!)
  s:(@+)(,-?\1):\2;:         # delete as many '@'s from 10^7, as found in unary
                             #input, and add one ';' (new unary digit)
tl                           # repeat (':l')
s:,::;s:@+;?@+::             # delete leftover stuff
s:-?:&0:;:c                  # prepend zero and start unary to decimal conversion
  s:\b9+:0&:                 # if only 9s found, prepend zero to them
  s:.9*;:/&:                 # separate the digit(s) that would change on increment
  h;s:.*/::                  # backup, delete all (non-changing) digits (till '/')
  y:0123456789:1234567890:   # increment changing digit(s)
  x;s:/.*::                  # delete changing digits from backup
  G;s:\n::                   # append backup, delete newline
  s:;::                      # delete one unary digit (';')
/;/tc                        # if unary portion left, repeat (':c')
:f                           # loop to generate floating-point number
  s:(\w)(,+),:\2\1:          # move 1 digit after the commas, and delete 1 comma
tf                           # repeat (':f')
s:,:.:                       # turn first comma into a decimal point
y:,:0:                       # turn the rest of commas into zeroes (final result)
                             # implicit printing
```

For a fast and safe version of the program, but less precise, you can [try this online](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#PVDLasMwELz7K2Ioxg9Zr8RJPDpEt/6EyKGBJoY2KZXADW1/ve6uwdmD2N3Rzs7sFBHkzxPEHHAYXIQoRVOVYawQbDBwacguDgSEEbBnd0e/3227zdoajSULaQWnViqneXiiUiGqPLkvmmsPEqDsmcllDbwzWQTO9GtU3xG@QfEI2vibKS/ag1c5gUcYzUGkF4YiSt9UoiS8EYtIvBHnkXqurmY4WATjgqWpxJindRlrQaHp@4klvPQNdMHWZF87qII3UFEr0nuHNna96ba7fY9HpjFbUmxjNhSuYAJHr3IqnTK8Usnn4zOK5YbcFJBMK6AxTZ2R9u/2kYbbNU7t5z8).

Answer (score 7):

## Javascript ES6, 6 bytes

```
x=>1/x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#S7P9X2FrZ6hf8T85P684PydVLyc/XSNNw9BAU/M/AA)

Javascript defaults to floating point division.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the way your created and called f(). Can you explain that a little, or suggest a reference?

Comment: @TecBrat This is an anonymous function. In the try it online link I have f= in the header to assign the anonymous function so that it can be called. In the footer I have console.log(f(whatever number)) to output the result of calling the function

Comment: Shouldn't your total be 8 Bytes then?

Comment: @TecBrat The anonymous function is an answer without having to assign it.

Comment: I'm not trying to argue. I'm trying to learn. How does this work?

Comment: @TecBrat The function is x=>1/x, which is equivalent to function(x){return 1/x}. As according to [this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11932/64505) in meta, which is referencing [this consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?page=1&tab=active#tab-top), anonymous functions that will perform the requested task are a valid answer to the challenge.

Comment: I was not familiar with arrow functions. I see there is a proposal for them in PHP. I hope it goes through. #ilearnedsomethingtoday

Answer (score 7):

## APL, 1 byte

```
÷
```

`÷` Computes reciprocal when used as monadic function. [Try it online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%F73&run)

Uses the Dyalog Classic character set.

Comment: [Encoding](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/9429#9429).

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes

The obvious solution would be

```
1/U
```

which is, quite literally, `1 / input`. However, we can do one better:

```
pJ
```

This is equivalent to `input ** J`, and `J` is set to -1 by default.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@1/g9f@/KQA)

Fun fact: as `p` is the power function, so `q` is the root function (`p2` = `**2`, `q2` = `**(1/2)`); this means that `qJ` will work as well, since `-1 == 1/-1`, and therefore `x**(-1) == x**(1/-1)`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org/), 5 bytes

```
1&(/)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cheddar#y0ktUUiz/W@opqGv@b@gKDOvRCNNw680Nym1yMoqOSM1JSWxSC@xKL0s2ihWU/P/fxMA)

This uses `&`, which bonds an argument to a function . In this case, `1` is bound to the left hand side of `/`, which gives us `1/x`, for an argument `x`. This is shorter than the canonical `x->1/x` by 1 byte.

---

Alternatively, in the newer versions:

```
(1:/)
```

Comment: New version lets this become `(1:/)` for same byte count

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 12 bytes

```
lambda x:1/x
```

One for 13 bytes:

```
(-1).__rpow__
```

One for 14 bytes:

```
1 .__truediv__
```

Answer (score 5):

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE), <s>6</s> <s>5</s> 2 bytes

```
Ans⁻¹
```

-1 byte thanks to [Timtech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114544/reciprocal-of-a-number-1-x?page=2&tab=votes#comment279524_114610).

-3 bytes with `Ans` thanks to [Григорий Перельман](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114544/reciprocal-of-a-number-1-x/114610?noredirect=1#comment279663_114610).

`Ans` and `⁻¹` are [one-byte tokens](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens).

TI-Basic implicitly returns the last value evaluated (`Ans⁻¹`).

Comment: Input also implicitly gets coordinate input into X and Y, but you couldn't use that since you need to be able to accept floating point numbers. Remember that X^-1 is only two bytes so you could save one there.

Comment: TI-Basic is allowed to take input from `Ans`, so you can replace this with `Ans⁻¹`

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 3 bytes

```
l_^
```

Try it at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=l_%5E&inputs=10&version=19.8.0)

**Explanation**

```
    % Implictily grab input
l_  % Push -1 to the stack
^   % Raise the input to the -1 power
    % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 4):

### Java 8, 6 bytes

```
x->1/x
```

Almost the same as the [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114547/34543).

Comment: Would this encounter any issues with integer division?

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 4 bytes

```
1/#&
```

Provides you with an exact rational if you give it an exact rational, and with a floating-point result if you give it a floating-point result.

Answer (score 4):

### ZX Spectrum BASIC, 13 bytes

```
1 INPUT A: PRINT SGN PI/A
```

Notes:

- Each line costs 2 bytes for the line number, 2 bytes for the length of the line and 1 byte for the newline
- Numeric literals are converted into binary at parse time, costing an extra 6 bytes, thus the use of `SGN PI` instead of literal `1`.
- Keywords take 1 byte each.

ZX81 version for 17 bytes:

```
1 INPUT A
2 PRINT SGN PI/A
```

Comment: Where can I find more specific information about how to score ZX Spectrum BASIC?

Comment: @LuisMendo You can find the character set (including keywords) on Wikipedia, but apart from that I don't know whether there is a consensus on scoring ZX Basic. (For instance, the ZX81 version must be a full program, but the ZX Spectrum supports INPUT as an immediate command.)

Comment: To save program listing bytes on the ZX81, you can do `LET A=17` and refactor your application to one line to `1 PRINT SGN PI/A`, you will need to change the value of A with more typing each time you want to run your program though.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 4 bytes

```hs
(1/)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@59mq2Gor/k/NzEzT8FWoaC0JLikyCdPQUWhOCO/HEilKRj/BwA)

Answer (score 4):

### R, 8 bytes

```
1/scan()
```

Pretty straightforward. Directly outputs the inverse of the input.

Another, but 1 byte longer solution can be : `scan()^-1`, or even `scan()**-1` for an additional byte. Both `^` and `**` the power symbol.

Answer (score 3):

### C, 30 bytes

```
float f(float x){return 1./x;}
```

Comment: You can remove the trailing `0` to save one byte. With `1.` it will still be compiled as a double.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Not in my testing. `1.` is still treated like an integer.

Comment: Works for me using `echo -e "#include <stdio.h>\nfloat f(x){return 1./x;}main(){printf(\"%f\\\\n\",f(5));}" | gcc -o test -xc -` Output of `./test` is `0.200000`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Oh crap, I mixed this up with my Ruby answer. Sorry!

Comment: Doesn't this take input as an integer instead of a float? It doesn't work for floats, [at least on gcc.](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@Wk59YopCmUaFZXZRaUlqUp2Cop19hXfs/M69EITcxM09Dk6uaSwEICoqAQmkaSqppSjpADUZ6ppqa1ly1/wE) `float f(float x){return 1/x;}` would work correctly.

Comment: @Steadybox woops

Comment: No need for the trailing `.` - C will happily implicitly convert `(int)1` to `(float)1` because of the type of `x`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
İ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@39kw////80B)

Comment: That's actually 2 bytes.

Comment: In UTF-8, sure. By default, Jelly uses a [custom SBCS](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) though.

Comment: @Dennis the wiki you linked says `Jelly programs consist of up to 257 different Unicode characters`.

Comment: @Khaled.K Yes, it also says *The character `¶` and the linefeed character can be used interchangeably*, so while Unicode mode "understands" 257 different characters, they map to 256 tokens.

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

**Edit:** saved 1 byte thanks to [Digital Trauma](/users/11259/digital-trauma)

```dc
7k1?/p
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@2@ebWivX/D/v4GeqaGxCQA)**

Because dc treats the input as commands, negative numbers are recognized using `_` as the negative sign, instead of `-`, which is interpreted as the subtraction command. This is allowed by this meta [consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10100/59010).

**Explanation:**

```dc
7k           # set precision to 7 digits. This is needed to output at least 4
             #significant figures when the input is '6431' for example)
1?           # push 1, then push input number
/p           # divide and print result
```

Comment: The `r` is unnecessary with a slight change: `4k1?/p`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma You're right, thanks. I rushed it. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 3 bytes

```perl6
1/*
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#LYjBCoMwEAXv7yv2INIWss1mk3oQv0VKSUFoLRgU/Pp0BS8zw6wl0/bgV4/vTu00b3mxM1S532qP8tzpfJdmvNL7t9BnmnOpnpNohAkBgb1VQBKDiHIHYdUOLnBSNcXIAucPpD8)

This also works, but is 5 or 6 bytes
You can use `⁻` (superscript minus) at 3 bytes, or `¯` (macron) which is 2 bytes

```perl6
*⁻¹
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25sqtVFDLzCtLLQKK2P7XOrT@0M7/1lzFiZUKUFENlXhNhbT8IoWczLzU4v8GeqaGxiZcQIrLiMtIzwDIMuIyNQQShobGeuZchnrGxuZcukZ6psbGQMrERM@QS9cARJgCAA)

Answer (score 3):

## C++ lambda function, 24 bytes

```
[](float x){return 1/x;}
```

Full program

```
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
    auto y = [](float x){return 1/x;} ;
    std::cout << y(5) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: In C++14 you can use `auto x` instead of `float x` to save a byte. Additionally, `main` should be declared as returning an int.

Answer (score 3):

## [Rogex](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Rogex), 15 bytes

```
701300001600200
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVTRbpswFH3PV3jpA4YAMWRN263WVFXVlJdtWh@TTDLBLGgEkCFbI@3fs2tDMnCcqA/1Qxzfe8659sG@5a5eF/nkthT7dFMWokbVrnKR4INS/EQUDYfD/Q0JJgRGMCUkJGQPsTYLv76oapGW2PbbuU1hwf1VsSnTjGPrCn@ivmP7zt/FeDHuLhwMfxfOYmy5QJh9/vL1@9Pjw/MTyG0jPBy6oGYbNec/mJcQ727pWHK/Ji5qyBu@oXOydMLrqRT6VlSUDKJtksBUsVjAlP1mGUyDmCdAymtcucyN7A8DBCNNEKPUIlazbEORFpKjFKni8jymlmUfczxrCYGRkBRiwyTPerHsHlkRmUZsSKu1wNV/9ODPGmxBzfnuM55jefiGVJQUFvMmt/yoYizoxEbBIRp2o@EhCh7JkpgFIxbabjCFeq0NoH3ig9xzYLAHxhViFYpYxaGUnpO00EyTQ30xuY00L7c1tm0d1JgVGmw@o6AOciIQmAXUzh@eH2ezgUm2EHF/Y0pMudP/dlBeElwWuOClBg11KNzdubyjSzN@0sFLqESOqNTXgO8NQM8EvDYAHRNwagCOTcCbDlCmRxSgGuZWw3gGzJ2GMUCY8ZUAzvCqFCHqEFQrONVcdSG7yucvaY2JLhR3UKqZSEtUM6jbDcBdW2okrnUUOBSiVPH7168oec5j6IBE6x7qmdJJL9ptBOge9VuB9t46bUFWthILsTw@1oOCxoeEIsHZr5OMOpkuyc1v8VBjRFHwOqHkspBnEmpdgCITzfvE4P07k/errKjOeu@9ofe88f5Q7y28P2dZW@P13vPLQpe89w7eH2/rPvwH)

<sup>The actual language isn't on TIO *yet*, so a python 3.8 interpreter with the program in the code section and the python interpreter split in the header and footer is provided</sup>

Rogex is a newly developed language that I've recently discovered, so I though I'd give it a crack and write an answer.

### Explained

```
701 300 # Set the buffer to 1 and place it in cell 0
001     # Get numeric input and place it into the buffer
600 200 # Divide cell 0 (1) by the buffer (input) and print
```

### (╭☞´• ᗜ •`)╭☞ 100 answers! Woot! (⌐■◡■)

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 10 bytes

```
->x{1.0/x}
```

Very simple

Answer (score 2):

## Quetzalcoatl, 3 bytes

```
cfI
```

`c` takes input, `f` converts to a float, and `I` takes the inverse.

Answer (score 2):

## Actually, 1 byte

```
ì
```

From the docs:

```
8D (ì): pop a: push 1/a
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@394zf//hgYA)

In Seriously, it would be two bytes:

```
,ì
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Seriously because Seriously doesn't do implicit input. You should also provide a TIO link.

Comment: Huh. I must have misremembered. Feel free to edit.

Comment: Actually, this is 2 bytes.

Comment: It's one Seriously/Actually byte. See the docs.

Comment: @Coder-256 *Actually* :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 3 bytes

*3 bytes saved thanks to @gggg*

```julia
inv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/M6/sf0FRZl5JTp4GkK1hoqnJhcw31DfW1PwPAA)

Returns the matrix inverse.

Comment: `inv` is just 3 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Bean](https://github.com/patrickroberts/bean), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

#### Equivalent JavaScript:

```
(1/A)
```

#### Bean xxd-style hexdump:

```
00000000: 4ca5 3a8e 2043                           L¥:. C
```

#### Explanation

`A` is auto-initialized with the 1st input line JSON-parsed. (e.g. `5` is interpreted as JSON and becomes a `number`), and the program implicitly outputs `1/A`.

**Edit** The "hack" I just realized is that removing the first byte of the AST binary doesn't seem to affect the compilation of the program...

[Try the demo here.](https://patrickroberts.github.io/bean/#h=TKU6jiBD&i=NQ==&f=0&w=1)

Comment: Interesting, what's the main cause of this being longer than vanilla JS even though it's basically compressed JS?

Comment: @ETHproductions The overhead of the block scope and I believe binary operators are each 2 bytes (This is due to the binary directly representing the AST of the equivalent JavaScript). Bean really shines with challenges that would typically require several calls to builtins, or when interpreting input as objects automatically saves bytes, or when having a program implicitly input and output is smaller than writing answer as a function where you explicitly input and output.

Comment: Weird... I just found an interesting hack.

Answer (score 2):

## Forth, 3 bytes

```
1/f
```

**[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/forth-gforth#M03VNflvqJ/2P03vPwA)**

Takes a floating point literal, which in Forth must be in scientific notation, like `5e-4` for `0.0005` or `2e3` for `2000.0`. The result will be left on the floating point stack.

[Reference on number conversion in Forth.](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Number-Conversion.html#Number-Conversion)

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <strike>7</strike> 6 bytes

*Saved a byte thanks to [David Conrad](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/794/david-conrad).*

```
x=>1/x;
```

Anonymous function which returns the inverse of a number.

Full program with test cases:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Func<double, double> f =
        x=>1/x;
        
        // test cases:
        Console.WriteLine(f(0.5134));
        Console.WriteLine(f(0.5));
        Console.WriteLine(f(2));
        Console.WriteLine(f(2.0));
        Console.WriteLine(f(0.2));
        Console.WriteLine(f(51.2));
        Console.WriteLine(f(113.7));
        Console.WriteLine(f(1.337));
        Console.WriteLine(f(-2.533));
        Console.WriteLine(f(-244.1));
        Console.WriteLine(f(-0.1));
        Console.WriteLine(f(-5));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to count the semicolon in C#. Imagine that the lambda was being passed to a function that took a `Func<double, double>` as a parameter; in that case, it wouldn't be followed immediately by a semicolon.

Comment: AFAIK you should submit separate languages as separate answers. This helps the leaderboard userscript detect them as separate posts.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
/₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@6//qKnx/3/L/1EA)

For the sake of completeness…

#### Explanation

`/`, by default, takes a list of 2 numbers `[A, B]` as input and unify its output with `A` divided by `B`.

When `/` has a subscript, it takes a single number as input unify its output with that number divided by the subscript. For example, `/₄₂` will divide the input number by `42`.

The only exception is if the subscript is `1` (because dividing by `1` is kind of useless). In that case, it unifies its output with the inverse of its input.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, 29 bytes

Golfed:

```
float i(float x){return 1/x;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
float i(float x)
{
    return 1 / x;
}
```

Pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

## bc <s>+ sh</s>, <s>14</s> 10 bytes

`1/read()<NEWLINE>`

Run bc with `-l` which sets the default scale to 20. That way both input and output have 20 digits after the decimal point.

Edit:
Thanks **DigitalTrauma** for a tip on changing the answer from bc + sh to pure bc. Saved 4 bytes.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!.  I think you can claim `1/read()<NEWLINE>` as a 10-scoring pure bc answer.  This would include +1 for the use of the -l flag to bc, as per standard rules

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Thanks for the tip! I'll change the answer. I've never used bc by itself, only inside sh scripts, so I didn't know it is possible to use `read()` to enter variables. Just found an example in bc man page that does something similar.

Comment: Why is it 10 bytes?  I count only 8 visible (one-byte) characters and one newline (of you really insist that this be part of the program).  Makes 9 bytes.  Where's the tenth?

Comment: @Alfe Yes, newline counts, since a number can't be read from stdin without it. The 10th byte comes from `-l` flag that is needed to achieve the required precision.

Answer (score 2):

### OCaml, 12

```
fun x->1./.x
```

The division of floats is done with the operator `/.`.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 24 bytes

```php
echo(1/(float)$argv[1]);
```

This is my first answer, tell me if I can somehow shorten it!
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#@29jX5BRoJCanJGvYaivkZaTn1iiqZJYlF4WbRiraf3//38TAA)

When trying it online, just change the argument to the desired number n of which you want to get `1/n`

*Very* straightforward approach.

Comment: I think you can replace `1` with `1.0` and then remove the `(float)` for some savings. I tried it in your TIO link and it seemed to work.

Comment: @Malivil but isn't $argv[1] originally a string and therefore has to be casted to a float?

Comment: I think it's doing implicit type casting. I tried it out in your TIO link and it was working. I also read though the PHP manual a bit (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and it seems like it just changes based on context.

Answer (score 2):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 1 byte

```lisp
/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc8xDoAgDIXh3VMwwmClFOJ5jJGEhCAKnr9G57L@31venlOrrNvRLxV1fMre01l4YWMmXe9U@h@3nFVUFgKSH4iUHVh57aQcUO6IBKsIQCTC7CAQyeI9oCh20MN3gl8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
Ė
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwixJYiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 6 bytes

```kotlin
{1/it}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sO78kJzNvwZ6yxByFNCsFDZf80qScVE0FXTsFCFPBVmFpaUmarsWyakP9zJJaCGdtQVFmXolGmoaRnoGmJkRswQIIDQA)

Simple anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 4 bytes

```
1rd/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@29YlKL//78xAA)

```
1     e# Push 1
 rd   e# Push input as a double
   /  e# Divide
```

Alternate solution:

```
rdW#

rd    e# Push input as a double
  W   e# Push -1
   #  e# Exponentiation
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>3</s> 2 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Steven  Hewitt*

```
c1
```

`c` is float division, with `1` and implicit input.

Comment: Pyth can fill in the `Q` implicitly, so `c1` works just as well.

Answer (score 1):

## Fortran 95, 23 bytes

```
function f(x)
f=1/x
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Mathics](http://mathics.github.io/), 4 bytes

```
1/#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/mathics#S7P9b6ivrPY/oCgzr8QhzcFEz@A/AA)

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 5 bytes

```
:?1/a
```

Explanation:

```
:    get input from the cmd line, named 'a'
?    PRINT
1/a  1/a
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 3 bytes

```scala
1/_
```

This defines a lambda equivalent to `x => 1/x` (`_` is a placeholder for the argument). Use by assigning it to a variable, then calling it, like this:

```scala
val f: Double => Double = 1/_
f(5) // 0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 7 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediates window function that takes input from cell `[A1]` of type `variant`and expecting a (floating-point) number and outputs its inverse to the VBE immediates window. Does not handle improperly formatted input.

```vba
?1/[A1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 11 bytes

```
(/ 1(read))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/racket#U85JzEtXKEpMzk4t@a@hr2CooFGUmpiiqfn/v66xsZ4BAA)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! It looks like the `.0 ` is not really necessary ([tio](https://tio.run/nexus/racket#U85JzEtXKEpMzk4t@a@hr2CoUZSamKKp@f@/rrGxHgA)).  You can assume that the input is a float so you don't need to go through the trouble of having the 1 be a float.

Comment: @WheatWizard thanks, and does that mean fractions are acceptable output (eg. `1/5` vs `0.2`)?

Comment: No, fractions are still not allowed its just that instead of doing `(/ 1.0 -33)` you can do `(/ 1 -33.0)` that is put the burden of float casting onto the input instead of your code.  If you look at the modified version of your code I provided you will see it still does output a float.

Comment: Thanks @WheatWizard, made the edit above. Just realized OP allowed `x.0` input format after reading the last three comments under main question.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 11

```
<?=1/$argn;
```

Run with `echo <n> | php -nR '<code`

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 15 Bytes

```
(x:Double)=>1/x
```

Don't think there's a shorter way to do this in Scala.

Comment: The input isn't limited to ints.

Comment: Oops. That's what happens when you write code golf solutions at 5 in the morning. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 2 bytes

```
Ansֿֿ ¹
```

You could also do `1/Ans` (3) or `Ans^~1` (4).

Answer (score 1):

## [Noodel](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/), 1 [byte](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/docs/code_page.html)

```
ẹ
```

A command that takes the first character of a string and places at the end, for numbers takes the reciprocal of the number. The interpreter for *Noodel* is written in *JavaScript* which has double precision floating point numbers.

[Try it:)](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/editor.html?code=%E1%BA%B9&input=5&run=false)

---

### How it works

```
  # Implicitly pushes the number onto the stack.
ẹ # Takes the reciprocal of the input.
  # Implicitly prints the top of the stack to the screen.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Elixir, 7 bytes

```
&(1/&1)
```

Anonymous function defined using the capture operator.

Full program:

```
f=
&(1/&1)

IO.inspect(f.(0.5134))  # 1.94779898714453
```

[Try it online!](http://elixirplayground.com/)

Answer (score 1):

## [NO!](https://github.com/ValyrioCode/NO), 31 bytes

NO! has 6 valid tokens: `NOno!?` and commands are made up of `NO` with the number of `O` determining the command.

```
NOOOOO?no!NOOOOOOOOOOO
NOOOOOOOO?no
```

###More readable

```
NOOOOO?                 NOOOOO is the divide command and ? starts the arguments
       no!              no is 1 and ! separates the arguments            
          NOOOOOOOOOOO  This takes input from STDIN.

NOOOOOOOO?              This outputs the result of the       line
          no                                           first 

The equivalent pseudocode:

output divide 1, input
```

Answer (score 1):

## Emacs Lisp, 11 bytes

```
(/ 1(read))
```

Elisp defaults to integer division, so the input will have to be given as floating point, e.g. 1.0 instead of 1. The engine evaluates the (read) statement to get the input and then evaluates the (/ ...) statement, and outputs the answer to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + bc, 12 bytes

```
bc -l<<<1/$1
```

bc defaults to integer division, which would be a problem, but running bc with the -l flag loads a math library that allows for floating point division. The $1 takes the first command line argument passed to the Bash script and the <<< passes the string with the expanded argument to bc.

Answer (score 1):

## [HODOR](https://github.com/ValyrioCode/Hodor), 100 bytes

```
Walder
Hodor?!
Hodor, Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor, Hodor,
HODOR!!
HODOR!!!
```

If you must know how it works, I'll tell you.

### Explanation

```
Walder                                                                       Hodor hodor
Hodor?!                                                                     Hodor hodor hodor HODOR
Hodor, Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor, Hodor,        Hodor hodor hodor hodor hodor hodor
HODOR!!                                                                     Hodor hodor hodor hodor hodor
HODOR!!!                                                                    Hodor hodor (Hodor hodor hodor)
```

1. 

> Walder - Start program

2. 

> Hodor?! - Take input from STDIN

3. 

> Hodor, Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor, Hodor, - Change accumulator value to it's reciprocal

4. 

> HODOR!! - Output accumulator value as number

5. 

> HODOR!!! - Kill Hodor (End the program)

Comment: "Wylis"? Someone didn't read the books. ;)

Comment: @MartinEnder I read them but couldn't be bothered to look for his name in them. They are other 4000 pages long altogether.

Comment: http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Hodor :)

Comment: @MartinEnder I can't believe I have defiled Hodor's memory like this! (Now I've got to go change all the answers!)

Answer (score 1):

## 8087 machine code, 4 bytes

```
d9 e8   |   fld1
d8 f1   |   fdiv st0, st1
```

The obvious/trivial solution. Expects input in register `st0`.

Answer (score 1):

## SenseTalk, 16 bytes

```
params r
put 1/r
```

**Explanation**

```
params r # accept input
put 1/r  # get the reciprocal
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 1 byte

```
⑱
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////0cSN//8DAA)

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 3 bytes[(SBCS)](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg/wiki/Code-Page)

```
1¿/
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y05N///f8NB@/f//jQE)
Divide 1 by friendly input

Comment: `⑱` for 1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194869/do-you-make-me-up/194982#194982), 3 bytes

You know, we can't beat the built-ins.

```
1S/
```

### Explanation

```
a1S  % Stack : 1 a
   / % Divide.(1/a)
     % Output.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 34 bytes

```go
func(a float64)float64{return 1/a}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZdBLCoMwEAZguvUUg3RhoKZ5aFsovUOhJwhiRKpRQuxGepJupNBD2dO0MVnFbOZnvsks5vWuumne9qK4i6qEVtTqHNVt32kDGGLZmjh6CA0SLp_ByPQ0x3JQRSJANp0whwz5OurSDFoB3Yunm_xubnZ02ZkgGCP4v6uulWlUQnBOebYD6RNCIXsLgNk2C5uYLG1MVmuYWxP-yKkTWwOilOOjtSWEiDl3aEOAKcM551ZdWnGWYerYppCJR7Km5RipvYW_7TS5-gM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 5 bytes

```factor
recip
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVBQlFpSUllQlJlXomDNxWWqZ8D1vyg1ObPgv95/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 1 byte

```
⅟
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//Uev8//9N9czNTC0A)

Just another language with a built-in one-byte reciprocal function

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, 40 bytes

The built-in data type `real` provides an *implementation-defined* approximation.

```pascal
function f(x:real):real;begin f:=1/x end
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 3 bytes

```
p%i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jellyfish#@1@gmvn/v4GeoZExAA)

Unary `%` computes the reciprocal. `i` is input, `p` is output.

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish/wiki), 4 bytes

```
1I,h
```

[Online interpreter link](https://golfish.herokuapp.com?code=1I%2Ch&input=3)

Answer (score 0):

## [Dyvil](https://github.com/dyvil/dyvil), 5 Bytes

```
1 / _
```

Unfortunately we need the extra white space because `/_` would be a single operator, and `1/ _` would parse differently

Usage:

```
let f: double -> double = 1 / _
print(f(2)) // 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 7 bytes

```
(/ 1 x)
```

Full function:

```
(define (f x)
  (/ 1 x))
```

Testing:

```
(f 1.56)
```

Output:

```
0.641025641025641
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript(ES7), 8 bytes

```
x=>x**-1
```

```js
f=x=>x**-1;
console.log(f(0.5134));
```

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk Oh dammit. Now I have to rollback to x**-1.

Comment: ** does not exist in ES6, it was added in ES7, which is why I specified your answer was ES7

Comment: The Seventh Edition, also known as ECMAScript 2016, intended to continue the themes of language reform, code isolation, control of effects and library/tool enabling from ES2015, includes two new features: the exponentiation operator (**) and Array.prototype.includes.

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 12 bytes

```
say 1/arg(1)
```

Divides 1 by first argument. Precision is decided by `NUMERIC DIGITS` but defaults to at least 9 decimals.

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>10</s> 7 bytes

```
$0=1/$0
```

Usage:

```
awk '$0=1/$1' <<< "some number here"
```

or use the TIO link : [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcaxFYAwDAPRXnOkjbGs@KViGGoGyPjGNPfvOW/V8JvX8Cq3pBYaBMK8L5DskLINmrQxw1Jq1jJi@p/EBw)

Explanation:
Replace the input line with its reciprocal.  This is then evaluated and the entire line is printed if the evaluation in non-zero. Since the result can't be `0` we don't need to worry about not receiving output.

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2.7, <s>17</s> 25 bytes

Full program:

```
print'%.4f'%(1.0/input())
```

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, <s>69</s> 67 + 39 (vbs section) = 106 bytes

<kbd>a.bat</kbd>

```
@for /f "skip=1" %%n in ('cscript //nologo b.vbs 1/%1')do @echo %%n
```

*Explanation:*

- *call VBScript to calculate 1/argument*
- *return the result*

<kbd>b.vbs</kbd>

```
WScript.Echo Eval(WScript.Arguments(0))
```

*Explanation:(my guess, I'm not good at VBS)*

- *return the result calculated by `Eval`*

---

### Test cases

*called from command line:*

```
>a.bat 0.5134
1.94779898714453

>a.bat -0.5
-2
```

---

Batch can't handle floating point division....

Comment: I can't test VBScript, but my feeling is, that if you change the VBS to `WScript.Echo 1/WScript.Arguments(0)`, and change `"1/%1"` into ` "%1"`, you could save some bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/L3viathan/Aceto) 1.0, <s>4</s> 3 bytes non-competing

Non-competing because the challenge predates Aceto. Assumes input number is on the stack, and leaves it on the stack.

```
1s:
```

`1` pushes 1 on the stack, `s` swaps the top two values, and `:` does floating point division.

Also, this is the first Aceto answer!

edit: Saved 1 byte

Answer (score 0):

## [CGL (CGL Golfing Language)](https://codepen.io/programmer5000/pen/zwYrVd), 6 bytes (non-competing)

This language postdates this challenge.

```
-÷Ⓧ
```

Explanation:

`-` decrements the current stack, so it is now -1, where input is placed

`÷` Divides the first element of the stack by the second if it exists, otherwise (this case) it divides 1 by the first (reciprocal)

`Ⓧ` Output the last stack item (the result of `÷`) and exit

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 4 bytes

```
(/)1
```

Currying FTW!

Comment: alternatively `(1/)`

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 57 bytes

```
f(x)==(y:=abs(x);y>9999 or y<0.0001=>"ObjFloatErr ";1./x)
```

test code and results

```
(21) -> [[i,f(i)] for i in [-2,-1,-0.0001,-0.00001,9999,10000]]
   (21)
   [[- 2.0,- 0.5], [- 1.0,- 1.0], [- 0.0001,- 10000.0],
    [- 0.00001,"ObjError 1/x"], [9999.0,0.0001000100 0100010001],
    [10000.0,"ObjError 1/x"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fourier (Non-Competing), 79 bytes

```
1~RI~X<0{1}{0-1~R45a}X*R~XL*2+2/2~UX{1}{0~U}10P10/X~DL+U~p10Pp~TD/To*T~A46aD-Ao
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/fourier#@29YF@RZF2FjUG1YW22gC@SZmCbWRmgF1UX4aBlpG@kb1YVGgOXqQmsNDQIMDfQj6lx8tEPrCoC8groQF/2QfK2QOkcTs0QXXcf8//9NAA)

This is non-competing for two reasons:

- Firstly, it does not fulfil the spec (it only works for inputs in the range `-10 <= x <= 10`
- Secondly, it uses the functions `L` and `P` which were added after the writing of this challenge

So, this answer poses a challenge: can you complete this challenge in Fourier in the range `-9999 <= x <= 9999`? There are two bounties up for grabs:

- ***100 Rep Bounty*** for the first solution to complete this task *without* using the new functions `L` (log 10) and `P` (power)
- ***50 Rep Bounty*** for the shortest solution to complete this task using the new functions `L` (log 10) and `P` (power)

Note that on the Fourier github repo (https://github.com/beta-decay/Fourier/tree/master/fourIDE/editor) the FourIDE is up to date with `L` and `P`.

#### To-do list

- Add explanation of code

Comment: For x=0 the 1/x=1/0 is not possible so the domain of function 1/x has to be [-a, -e] [e,a] for some 'a' big enough for them and 'e' little enough...

Answer (score 0):

## [Convex](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex), 1 byte

```
¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/convex#@39o5////w0NjfXMAQ)

Answer (score 0):

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) , 11 Bytes

```
²Nṭ1,0ÆrḢ×Ṡ
```

This works without the built-in inverse function `Ị`. (Who uses that anyway?).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ARwA4///wrJO4bmtMSwww4Zy4biiw5fhuaD///8tOTk5)

**How it works**

```
²Nṭ1,0ÆrḢ×Ṡ
   1,0      # Look at the list [1,0]
  ṭ         # Append (to the end)
²N          #  the negative of the square of the input
      Ær    # Find the roots to the polynomial with coefficients corresponding to the list as [greater root,lower root] pair
        Ḣ   # Head; get the first element of the roots (always positive)
         ×Ṡ # Multiply by the sign of the input (to accommodate negative input)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 7 bytes

The obvious subroutine.

```
{1/pop}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that you could only omit the `sub` when passing it to a subroutine with a `&` prototype.

Comment: @quartata, [`perldoc perlsub`](//perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Signatures) says: "The signature is part of a subroutine's body. Normally the body of a subroutine is simply a braced block of code."

Comment: Still, the result is not something that is callable as it stands. I would say it is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)**, 15 bytes**

```
dc -e"Fk$1_1^p"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PyVZQTdVyS1bxTDeMK5A6f///@YA)

```
dc               ::Use dc calculation
   -e            ::Evaluate argument as dc code
     "         " ::Quote
      Fk         ::F sig-figs (F is hex for 15)
        $1       ::$1 is initial value (the first argument)
           _1^   ::Raise $1 to power of -1
              p  ::Print result
```

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 9 bytes

```
{1.0g/it}
```

Needs the `.0g` to denote big decimal notation on the 1, making the it unbox itself as a BigDecimal.

Input of `7.29349129124513204632593467635245678734521456789`

Results in `0.13710854789123656486815482305643737234188188122`

If you use an input of `214700000000000`, however, without the `.0g`...

You get an error or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 3 bytes

```lua
1/x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/99Qv@I/kDQAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), 4 bytes

```
1&`/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3vkpqWmZcarZKm899QLUH/fyxXQFFmXomDV35mnpqSgq6dgpJDmHKagq2dQjSXgoKBnqmhsYkOiNZRMAIiPQMQB8gyNQSRhobGeuZASs/YGEjpGumZGhuDaBMTPUMgbQAmTbli/wMA)

This is division (`` `/ ``) left-bonded with `1`, which is equivalent to reciprocal.

Answer (score 0):

## [KoopaScript](https://github.com/Jhynjhiruu/KoopaShell), 48 bytes

```
def a i inp;setath o 1 / \%vuserInput;print \%vo
```

And how it works (KS isn't really golfable yet but it's fun nonetheless):

```
def a i                                          - define a function and call it a lot
        inp;                                     - pause execution until input
            setath o 1 / \%vuserInput;           - set 'o' to 1 / the input
                                      print \%vo - output 'o'
```

[Try it online](https://jhynjhiruu.github.io/KoopaShell/host/ksmn.swf) (paste the code into the left-hand box, press enter, then type a number, press enter, etc)

Now that KS has input, I can finally start using it for stuff that involves interaction :D
(Tell me if this should be non-competing :P)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 1 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 0.82 bytes

```
o
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYL8yE0lLtgoSmEAQA)

Built-in solution.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ị
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWix_u7lpSnJRcDOUvWGgKYQAA)

Built-in.

#### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ÆtÆCÆsÆT
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWaw63lRxucz7cVny4LWRJcVJyMVRiwUJTCAMA)

Uses the fact that: $$\tan(\arcsin(\cos(\arctan(x)))) \equiv {{1} \over {x}}$$