# What characters are more common in my MD2 hash?

Tags: code-golf, string, hashing

**The challenge is simple**

Write a script that, when given a string input, will hash the string using the [MD2 hashing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD2_(cryptography)), and then return either a positive integer or negative integer output based on which character set below is more common in the resulting hash as a hexadecimal string:

```
01234567 - (positive)
89abcdef - (negative)
```

- The input will always be a string, but may be of any length up to 65535
- The entire input, whitespace and all, must be hashed
- For the purposes of this challenge, the integer 0 is considered neither positive nor negative (see tie output)
- The more common set is the one who's characters are more common within the 32 character hexadecimal hash string
- Your output may contain trailing whitespace of any kind, as long as the only non-whitespace characters are a valid truthy or falsey output
- In the event of a tie, where the hexadecimal string contains exactly 16 characters from each set, the program should output a 0

**I/O Examples**

```
Input: "" (Empty String)
Hash: 8350e5a3e24c153df2275c9f80692773
Output: 1

Input: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy cog" (Without quotes)
Hash: 6b890c9292668cdbbfda00a4ebf31f05
Output: -1

Input: "m" (Without quotes)
Hash: f720d455eab8b92f03ddc7868a934417
Output: 0
```

**Winning Criterion**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), fewest bytes wins!

Comment: It would be good to link to or ideally explain the MD2 hashing algorithm in the challenge specification to make it self contained.

Comment: @MartinEnder Will do!

Comment: I think it would be fair to simply accept three distinct values for _win_, _lose_, and _tie_

Comment: @mathjunkie true, probably shouldn't be changing the spec so much, but I guess just having 1, 0 or -1 is the best way

Comment: Hi there! Since others haven't mentioned it yet, I'll toss out a recommendation to use the [Sandbox](http://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) for future challenges, where you can get meaningful feedback and tighten up the challenge before posting on Main.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Ah thanks! Had I know about that I'd've definitely done so before posting it, will keep that in mind for the future, thanks!

Comment: "are a valid truthy or falsey output" Shouldn't it be a valid integer...? "Your output may contain trailing whitespace of any kind, as long as the only non-whitespace characters..." The first part says **trailing** whitespace is allowed, but the second part implies **leading and trailing** whitespace are allowed. Which is it?

Comment: This strikes me as a [chameleon challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8214/20260). Either your language has a build-in or library to do MD2 and the rest is simple character counting, or it doesn't and you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: @xnor A lot of challenges are trivial in some language and difficult in others. Take the [reciprocal challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114544/reciprocal-of-a-number-1-x) for instance... Many languages already have a function for this or at least support division. Some answers are in languages that don't and those answers seem to generally get more attention. It all comes down to [not upvoting trivial solutions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10132/51785)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Octave, 35 bytes

```matlab
@(s)diff(hist(hash('md2',s),+'78'))
```

*Requires the latest version of Octave (at least 4.2).

Computes histcounts of the hash string with it's center of bins are 7 and 8 then computes the difference of counts.

Comment: Given it's been a few days I'll put yours up as the winning answer, if somebody comes along later with a shorter solution I can always change it. Well done!

Answer (score 8):

### Mathematica, 43 bytes

```
Tr@Sign[15-2#~Hash~"MD2"~IntegerDigits~16]&
```

Outputs the number of digits in `01234567` minus the number of digits in `89abcdef`.

Comment: Too bad that `3E` is between 8 and 9 and not between 7 and 8. :|

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6), 731 bytes

This monster is implementing the MD2 algorithm, so it's embarrassingly long. Based on [js-md2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-md2) by Chen Yi-Cyuan.

```js
let f =

m=>{L=x=s=b=0,n=m.length,M=[],X=[],C=[],S=[...atob`KS5DyaLYfAE9NlSh7PAGE2KnBfPAx3OMmJMr2bxMgsoem1c8/dTgFmdCbxiKF+USvk7E1tqe3kmg+/WOuy/ueqloeZEVsgc/lMIQiQsiXyGAf12aWpAyJzU+zOe/95cD/xkws0iltdHXXpIqrFaqxk+4ONKWpH22dvxr4px0BPFFnXBZZHGHIIZbz2XmLagCG2Alra6wufYcRmFpNEB+D1VHoyPdUa86w1z5zrrF6iYsUw1uhSiECdPfzfRBgU1Satw3yGzBq/ok4XsIDL2xSniIlYvjY+ht6cvV/jsAHTny77cOZljQ5KZ3cvjrdUsKMURQtI/tHxrbmY0znxGDFA`].map(c=>c[O='charCodeAt']());for(l=1;l-2;){for(j=19;j--;)M[j]=M[16+j]||0;for(i=s;i<16;x++)L=(x-n||(b+=i-s,s=i-16,l=2),C[i]^=S[(M[i++]=x<n?m[O](x):16-(b&15))^L]);for(i=0;i<l;i++){for(j=16;j--;)X[32+j]=(X[16+j]=(i?C:M)[j])^X[j];for(t=j=0;j<18;t=t+j++&255)for(k=0;k<48;)t=X[k++]^=S[t]}}for(i=16,n=-i;i--;)n+=!(X[i]&8)+!(X[i]&128);return n}

console.log(f(''))
console.log(f('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy cog'))
console.log(f('m'))
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Really nice effort.

Comment: Props for, thus far, being the only one to actually implement the full MD2 algorithm rather than using built-in functions.

Comment: Highest byte answer deserving of more points.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2 + [Crypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto-module.html), <s>108</s> <s>99</s> <s>93</s> <s>91</s> <s>87</s> 78 bytes

Python doesn't have a native builtin for MD2.

```python
from Crypto.Hash import*
lambda s:sum(x<'8'for x in MD2.new(s).hexdigest())-16
```

<sub>*Saved 12 bytes thanks to @ovs.*</sub>
<sub>*Saved 9 bytes thanks to @FelipeNardiBatista.*</sub>

Comment: `lambda s:cmp(sum((int(x,16)<8)-.5for x in MD2.new(s).hexdigest()),0)` should reduce the byte count to 93

Comment: @ovs Very clever!

Comment: `sum(x<'8'for x ......`

Comment: `lambda s:sum(x<'8'for x in MD2.new(s).hexdigest())-16` for 78. the output can be any number, not just `-1,0,1`

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, 173 bytes

*-4 thanks to dzaima*

*-128 thanks to Oliver, this is basically his answer now.*

```
a->{String h="";for(byte b:java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD2").digest(a.ge‌​tBytes()))h+=h.forma‌​t("%02x",b);return h.codePoints().filter(c->c>47&&c<56).count()-16;}
```

Positive for truthy. Negative for falsy. 0 for 0.

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by removing the enclosing brackets of `for` and `if`

Comment: bytes to hex can be golfed: `String s="";for(byte b:bytes)h+=h.format("%02x",b);`. Also, you don't need to write a full program, but a lambda suffice: `a->{... return x;}`. Finally the for loop can be replaced by `int x=s.codePoints().filter(c->c>47&&c<56).count();`. All in all, I get 173 for your algorithm, golfed: `a->{String h="";for(byte b:java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD2").digest(a.getBytes()))h+=h.format("%02x",b);return h.codePoints().filter(c->c>47&&c<56).count()-16;}`. More golfing is possible, but this is a net improvement in byte count, isn't it?

Comment: Some things to golf: `println` -> `print` and `for(char c:s.toCharArray())if("01234567".contains(""+c))x++;` -> `for(String c:s.split(""))if("01234567".contains(c))x++;`

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I don't know much about Java 8, I switched to Groovy/Grails around the same time.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 50 Bytes

prints 1 for truthy and -1 for false and 0 for a tie

```
<?=preg_match_all("#[0-7]#",hash(md2,$argn))<=>16;
```

## PHP, 58 Bytes

prints 1 for truthy and -1 for false and 0 for a tie

```
<?=16<=>strlen(preg_filter("#[0-7]#","",hash(md2,$argn)));
```

Comment: Sorry for all the spec changes, final output requirements are in now.
Basically what you currently have but reversed (1 for truthy, -1 for falsey) which should be fairly easy as iirc in PHP `-0 === 0`

Comment: @Mayube this is too long 1 Byte more is enough. The best way is to specified the output by the possibilities of the language and not general

Comment: `echo 16<=>strlen(preg_filter("#[0-7]#","",hash(md2,$argn)));` should do the trick without additional byte.

Comment: Golfed version: `<?=preg_match_all("/[0-7]/",hash(md2,$argn))<=>16;`

Comment: @Christoph I feel like an idiot that I have not think about preg_match_all

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl + [Trf package](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/479), 79

```tcl
package require Trf
puts [expr [regexp -all \[0-7\] [hex -m e [md2 $argv]]]-16]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/tcl#NY6xDoIwGIR3n@LSsDZRB30RttKh1h9QKK1/C6KEx3bGOni54ZIv@XK1ZzK2RaKYrImERZQt4THebIcL@@eA2s@4jy5E@IkYKePevF@wvhEQuU6sWHbIiZRguJlQ/H1bMLYzDYEpO5lQcr0LY4pQNAeGYmrygDR9j0rt5bnSUC3NkA4E5a5HFD@l1loeTnpbt819Bi9tfk1f). (Thanks @Dennis for adding Tcl to TIO.)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 56 bytes

```
while($i<32)${hash(md2,$argn)[$i++]>'7'}++;echo$$_<=>16;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java <s>137</s> <s>130</s> <s>124</s> 123 bytes

```
a->{int c=32;for(int b:java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD2").digest(a.getBytes()))c-=(b>>6&2)+(b>>2&2);return c;}
```

[Test it online!](http://ideone.com/ZhhksK)

Basically, for each byte, we're asked to check against its 4th and 8th least significant bits. I don't go through the hex representation at all. So it seemed only natural to start playing with bits.

Values `<0` are falsey, values `>0` are truthy, value `0` is neither truthy or falsey. The usual truthy and falsey can't be applied to Java this time (because it can't be `true` or `false` or `0` with the rule `if(<truthy>)`), so I took the liberty to declare as such.

### Saves

1. 137 -> 130 bytes: golfed by using bit operations, removing 2 everytime I get a "falsy" bit.
2. 130 -> 124 bytes: more bitwise operations
3. 124 -> 123 bytes: replaced `byte` by `int` in the for loop declaration.